# setOnItemClickListener on custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `ListView`. This `ListView` contains 1 **Image** and 6 **TextView**s. To retrieve the value I have created a `setOnItemClickListener(...)`. Whenever I click on the `ListView` how could I actually retrieve all the data from the 6 **TextView**s?

Answer (score 60):

**Sample Code:**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
   } 
});
```

In the sample code above, the `listItem` should contain the selected data for the `textView`.

Comment: guys i am not able to sense the touch even if i write a toast inside onItemClick it is not showing

Comment: @abhishek , same issue with me also

Answer (score 14):

I too had that same problem..
If we think logically little bit we can get the answer.. 
It worked for me very well..
I hope u will get it..

1. `listviewdemo.xml`

   ```
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="30dp"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp" />
   ```
2. `listviewcontent.xml` - **note that `TextView`** - `android:id="@+id/txtLstItem"`

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/listviewcontentlayout"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/img1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtLstItem"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
               android:shadowRadius="5"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

       </LinearLayout>

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/img2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. `ListViewActivity.java` - **Note that** `view.findViewById(R.id.txtLstItem)` - 
   as we setting the value to `TextView` by `setText()` method we getting text from `TextView` by `View` object returned by `onItemClick` method. `OnItemClick()` returns the current view.

   ```
   TextView v=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLstItem);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item Name is "+v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
   ```

   Using this simple logic we can get other values like `CheckBox`, `RadioButton`, `ImageView` etc.

   ```
   ListView List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
   cursor = cr.query(CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
   adapter = new ListViewCursorAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.listviewcontent, cursor, from, to);

   cursor.moveToFirst();

   // Let activity manage the cursor
   startManagingCursor(cursor);

   List.setAdapter(adapter);
   List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View view,int position, long arg){
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLstItem);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item Name is " + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   );
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If in the listener you get the root layout of the item (say `itemLayout`), and you gave some id's to the textviews, you can then get them with something like `itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1)`.

Comment: @kangalert you're welcome. remember to mark the accepted answers (click on the checkmark next to the answer), to let people know that's a working solution. it also raises yours and answerer's reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, I found that the problem was I already had an android:onClick event in my layout file (which I inflated for the ListView rows). This was superseding the onItemClick event.

Answer (score 1):

If above answers don't work maybe you didn't add return value into getItem method in the custom adapter see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328804/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-for-custom-listview-but-working-in) question and check out first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for coding with Kotlin.
But I faced the same problem.
I solved with the code below.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener{ _, view, _, _ ->
        val text1 = view.find<TextView>(R.id.～～).text

        }
```

You can put an id which shows a TextView that you want in "～～".

Hope it'll help someone!