# How do I get the position of a ListView cell when a button within it is touched?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

Here is some of the XML of a `Button` that is on every cell in my `ListView`:

```
android:onClick="buttonTouched"
```

And this is what is called on my ListActivity:

```
public void buttonTouched(View v) 
{
    // how do I get the "position" of the cell this view is on?
}
```

How do I get the cell `position` of the button that was touched?

Comment: what you want to do actually ?

Comment: Each cell will have three buttons, and I need to know which exact position was clicked because each button will do something separate.

Comment: then you can get that buttons's id . i think you should not get that position.

Comment: how do I set the id of a button and then retrieve it later?

Comment: You Get that by view class . View.getParent(); try it some answer is easy to you check it .

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // What you want
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I had a number of buttons on the same row, I ended up just setting a tags in my adapter to the positions needed and then getting the tag on button touch:

```
public void imageClick(View v) 
{
    int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
}
```

The reason I went this route is because I needed to have the click done in the ListActivity to access some data I needed there that wasn't in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this: [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Implementation Example: [setOnItemClickListener on custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709870/setonitemclicklistener-on-custom-listview).

Since you have 3 buttons in each row of the list view and you have 3 diff implementation for them, there is another way of doing this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(null == convertView){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_RESOURCE, null);
        holder.btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        holder.btn2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        holder.btn3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        //setting tag to reduce hierarchy lookup
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        //getting tag to obtain the already found views
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Updating fields
    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(commonListener); 
    holder.btn2.setOnClickListener(commonListener); 
    holder.btn3.setOnClickListener(commonListener); 
    //returning the populated view
    return convertView;
}

OnClickListener commonListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn1:
                //do your work
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                //do your work
                break;
                case R.id.btn3:
                //do your work
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }); 
/**
 * Holder class to improve performance. Helps in reducing the lookup for
 * views.
 * 
 */
private static class ViewHolder {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
}
```

Hope this helps.