# Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemSelectListener?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have been working on RecyclerView and CardView recently provided by Android L.
Both of them are quite impressive but I got disappointed when I wanted to use onItemSelectListener with RecyclerView and couldn't find such method.
Help needed.

Comment: Maybe [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener) can provide the answer.

Comment: No I don't think it is an answer to my question. @ewit

Comment: The answer on that question explains that due to the changes in how the RecyclerView is constructed there isn't really an item to select. This due to further abstractions to arbitrary views. Which answers the "why". You never asked the question: "How do I get around it/create an onselect listener?".

Comment: Do you know how can I create an onselect listener ?