# Difference b/w getLayoutPosition() & getAdapterPosition()

Tags: android

Can anyone explain me the basic difference between getLayoutPosition() & getAdapterPosition()?

[RecyclerView.ViewHolder - getLayoutPosition vs getAdapterPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684154/recyclerview-viewholder-getlayoutposition-vs-getadapterposition)

This answer talks about particular case.But I want to know the difference in general.

Comment: In what context and what does the documentation say those methods do?

Comment: You say that the answer you've linked talks about a particular case, but it doesn't entirely. It explains why they are different, in addition to some extra details for that specific case, but explaining how they are different should give you a general answer, right?