# How to get current position in horizontal list view

Tags: android

**Main Activity.java**  code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myHorizontalListView = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.horizontallistview);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, itemsArray, data);
        myHorizontalListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myHorizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                rank = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
                country = new String[]{"China", "India", "United States",
                        "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                        "Russia", "Japan"};
                population = new String[]{"1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                        "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                        "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000"};

                //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);


                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country, population);
                // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
                Log.e("cccccccccccccchhhhhh","" + position);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewPagerActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("rank", rank);
                        i.putExtra("country", country);
                        i.putExtra("population", population);
                        i.putExtra("position", position);
                        Log.e("cccccccccccccchhhhhh", "::::::::::" + position);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }

                });


                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter** code :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] itemsArray;
    String[] data;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, String[] itemsArray, String[] data) {
        context = c;
        this.itemsArray = itemsArray;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemsArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemsArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView itemtext;
        TextView data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        View rowView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder.itemtext = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemtext);
        holder.data = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);

        holder.itemtext.setText(itemsArray[position]);
        holder.data.setText(data[position]);


        return rowView;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you expect? to get the current position, you have to get it inside setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: expect to me....I'm clicked myHorizontalListView(Horizontal listview data) get the position

Comment: @mujjuraja try this way  "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,position+ " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();"

Comment: dear @HardikParmar.  Print Toast is  only for checked position. Not any ony using

Comment: @mujjuraja so what u want ??

Comment: You are doing setOnItemClickListener inside another one... you should split it, one by one, I think that's the best way

Comment: ok. My reqment : show the all data in horizontal listview. and second any one data clicked, first of all position get to data set in listview.. Ex: Horizontallistview data position 4 clicked to set data in llist view but start position 4... Ok Got it

Comment: @M.Mariscal..  i will try yr suggestion

Comment: @mujjuraja isn't this question a duplicate of [Get clicked item and its position in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview)?

Comment: @Sufian thank dude but my prob solved. yr late suggestion. Thanks