# How to populate RecyclerView from string resource

Tags: java, android

I'm getting string `id` instead of string value in `recyclerview`.

Below is my code, I don't know where i'm getting it wrong.

```
public class Albert_Einstein_Fragment extends Fragment {
private String b;

String[] dataArray ={String.valueOf(R.array.albert_array)};

//...

private class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuoteHolder>{
    private String[] dataSource;
    public QuoteAdapter(String[] dataArgs){
        dataSource = dataArgs;

    }
    @Override
    public QuoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_quotes, parent, false);
        return new QuoteHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(QuoteHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTaskNameTextView.setText(dataSource[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSource.length;
    }
}
}
}
```

Below is part of my array string resource code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="albert_array">
    <item>Let every man be respected as an individual and no man idolized.   </item>
    <item>God does not play dice. </item>
    <item>Great spirits have always encountered violent opposition from mediocre minds.</item>
    <item>Only a life lived for others is a life worthwhile.</item>
    <item>We shall require a substantially new manner of thinking if mankind is to survive.</item>
    <item>I used to go away for weeks in a state of confusion.</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Below is the output of my code

```
2131427328
```

Instead of list of strings in my array string resource

Comment: You're not retrieving your `String` array Resource correctly. Remove the initialization in the declaration line, and add the following in `onCreateView()`: `dataArray = activity.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.albert_array);`.

Comment: Wow! Works Perfectly! Thank you! thank you! But i changed `getIntArray()` to `getStringArray()` Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, jeez, yeah, that was a typo. My bad. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Comment: How do i connect with you sir? In case.

Comment: Wow! I which i could live like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve a `String` array resource, you need to use the `Resources#getStringArray()` method. You can get access to your app's `Resources` with the `getResources()` method, which must be called on a `Context`; in your case, the `Activity` will suffice.

Remove the initialization from `dataArray`'s declaration line:

```
private String[] dataArray;
```

And add the following in the `onCreateView()` method, after you've initialized `activity`;

```
dataArray = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.albert_array);
```

Comment: How do i get the actual clicked view ?

Comment: There's an example in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview).