# How to get a position of item in recyclerview to a activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

friends I created an dialogfragment which consist of a recyclerview. in that recyclerview I added some image and text.when I select the particular image it should be selected means I want the position of that particulars get to my activity and dialog fragment is dismiss, I go through the various sited but didn't understand. can anyone please tell me,new to the programming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find your answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview) avoid posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your activity that shows the dialog fragment as below

```
public void onRecyclerItemSelected(int position){
    yourDialog.dismiss();
}
```

To call this method from your dialog fragment, capture click of recycler view using interface from adapter. So whenever recycler view is clicked you can call your activity method from dialog fragment using

```
if(getActivity()!=null && getActivity() instanceOf YourActivity){
    ((YourActivity)getActivity().onRecyclerItemSelected(pos);
}
```

Where pos is the int pos of recycler item clicked.
Hope you understand. Any doubts please let me know.

Comment: I didn't understand "capture click of recycler view using interface from adapter." can you please give some more info

Comment: have a look at the link to know know how to have on item click listener.  http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/