# How can I make a single search for two different lists belonging to different activities in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two different activities :

one having department list and another activity having employee list.

I want to add search functionality to my app such that it can search data for all activities from a single activity.
Please suggest if it is possible and how ?

For code you can refer [How to pass data collected in arraylist from json asset file in one activity having recyclerview to another activity again having recycler view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903982/how-to-pass-data-collected-in-arraylist-from-json-asset-file-in-one-activity-hav/42904041#42904041)

Comment: have you tried anything ? if so please post the sample of your code

Comment: @KishanCS : You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903982/how-to-pass-data-collected-in-arraylist-from-json-asset-file-in-one-activity-hav/42904041#42904041 for the code. I added addtextlistener method.

Comment: Implement search in base activity and extends your all activities with that base activity.

Comment: @Piyush : can you give me the example acc to the code in this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903982/how-to-pass-data-collected-in-arraylist-from-json-asset-file-in-one-activity-hav/42904041#42904041 ?

Comment: So, the search will be in another activity or fragment, right? What you need is, to implement logic for search the query inside different available models and display the result lists (of different models) inside a single search result list.

Comment: @Nizam : not exactly! I want that if i have activity A and activity B : then when i use search in activity A , it should also show the content of activity B alongwith activity A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 2):

That means you need to search data of all Activity in single `Activity`.

So you need to add include conman `SerchView` in `xml` file of all `Activities`.  Also Implement `BaseActivity`  that holds search Implementation  for all of your Acclivities.

Comment: I did it  but its not working. Could you please suggest something else?