# Android get selectd part of text on recyclerview item and position

Tags: android

in my adapter items can be selectable for show popup such as `copy`, `cut` or etc, now how can i get selected part of text on `recyclerView` item and position? i read more document about found this solution but i dont know how can i do that

this is my adapter which i would like to get selected part of text and postion:

```
public class ShowBookContentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowBookContentsAdapter.ShowBookContentsViewHolder> {
    private List<Contents> list;
    private Context        context;

    ...

    private fontFace setFontFace = fontFace.SHABNAM;

    public ShowBookContentsAdapter(List<Contents> items, Context mContext, IonChangeBottomViewVisibility mOnChangeBottomViewVisibility, IonSelectText mIonSelectText) {
        list = items;
        context = mContext;

        ionChangeBottomViewvisibility = mOnChangeBottomViewVisibility;
        ionSelectText = mIonSelectText;
    }

    @Override
    public ShowBookContentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int layout = -1;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                layout = R.layout.item_book_content_paragraph;
                break;
        }

        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ShowBookContentsViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShowBookContentsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (list.get(position).getContentType()) {
            case 0:
                makeSelectable(holder.book_content_paragraph);
                implementingParagraphView(holder, position);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void implementingParagraphView(final ShowBookContentsViewHolder mHolder, final int position) {
        holder = mHolder;

        String content = list.get(position).getContent();
        mHolder.book_content_paragraph.removeAllViews();
        try {
            Reader reader = new StringReader(content);

            KetabkhanView         ketabkhan             = new KetabkhanView(context);
            KetabkhanTagProcessor ketabkhanTagProcessor = new KetabkhanTagProcessor();

            ketabkhanTagProcessor.parse(reader, ketabkhan);
            mHolder.book_content_paragraph.addView(ketabkhan);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("E ", e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        makeSelectable(mHolder.book_content_paragraph);

        if (setFontFace == fontFace.SHABNAM)
            Utils.overrideFonts(context, mHolder.book_content_paragraph, PersianFontType.SHABNAM);
        else if (setFontFace == fontFace.SAHEL)
            Utils.overrideFonts(context, mHolder.book_content_paragraph, PersianFontType.SAHEL);

        //for show and hide bottom view
        mHolder.book_content_paragraph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ionChangeBottomViewvisibility != null) {
                    ionChangeBottomViewvisibility.onChange();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...
    private void makeSelectable(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                makeSelectable((ViewGroup) child);
            } else if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) child).setTextIsSelectable(true);
                ((TextView) child).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize == 0 ? 14 : textSize);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return list.get(position).getContentType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(int itemId) {
        return itemPositions.get(itemId);
    }

    public void setData(List<Contents> mContents) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(mContents);
    }

    public class ShowBookContentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Nullable
        @BindView(R.id.book_content_paragraph)
        LinearLayout book_content_paragraph;

        ...
        public ShowBookContentsViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

i make selectable text on items by this method: `makeSelectable()`

Comment: Did you try adding android:textIsSelectable option to textView ?

Comment: @abdulrahmank selecting text is not my problem, i can't get selected part of text after selected by user and position of row

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the same using custom ActionMode Callback. We can set the custom Action Mode callback to a particular textview of recycler view item by setting **textView.customSelectionActionModeCallback** in the onBindViewHolder of recyclerView Adapter. In the custom Callback we can use the current position and selected text.
onBindViewHolder will look like this.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //code
    holder.textview. setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new CustomSelectionCallback(holder.taskName, position, mContext));
```

}

In the custom Callback we can send anything along with the position of the item.
Custom Selection Callback can be implemented as follows.

```
public class CustomSelectionCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

private TextView mTextView;
private int position;
private Context mContext;

public CustomSelectionCallback(TextView text, int pos, Context context) {
    this.mTextView = text;
    this.position = pos;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    int start = mTextView.getSelectionStart();
    int end = mTextView.getSelectionEnd();
    Spannable wordtoSpan = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), start, end,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    //copy the text when Copy Action Mode is clicked
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.copy) {
        copyText(start, end);
        mode.finish();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.shareText) {
        shareText(start, end);
        mode.finish();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.selectAll) {
        selectAllText();
        return true;
    }
    return true;

}

/**
 * implement select all functionality id ActionMOde Menu
 */
private void selectAllText() {
    Selection.setSelection((Spannable) mTextView.getText(), 0, mTextView.length());
}

private void shareText(int start, int end) {
    CharSequence selectedTxt = mTextView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
    String shareBody = selectedTxt.toString();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "SHARE"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

/**
 * copy the selected text with start and end param to clipboard
 *
 * @param start start point of selection of the text view
 * @param end   end point of selection of the text view
 */
private void copyText(int start, int end) {
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) mContext.
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    CharSequence selectedTxt = mTextView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("selected text label", selectedTxt);
    assert clipboardManager != null;
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, selectedTxt.toString() + "   position  " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}