# Multiple selected items are not staying highlighted

Tags: java, android

When i choose an item from listview, it turns gray but when I select another item in the listview then the previous highlighted item turns to default color and the new item turns to gray. What I want is to stay both of them to be highlighted, and when a click on the highlighted items they should turn back to normal as well.

My code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.conversationList);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new conversationsMultipleChoiceListener());
listView.setAdapter(conversationsAdapter);
((ConversationsAdapter) conversationsAdapter).updateConversations(conversationsList);
listView.setLongClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        Conversation item = (Conversation) conversationsAdapter.getItem(position);
        startChat(item, false);
    }
});


private class conversationsMultipleChoiceListener implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();




        switch (checkedCount) {
            case 0:
                mode.setSubtitle(null);
                break;
            default:
                mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " konuşma seçildi");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.conversation_actions, menu);
        mode.setTitle("Konuşmalarınız");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sil:
                Log.w("action","sil");
                mode.finish();
                break;
            case R.id.blokla:
                Log.w("action","blokla");
                mode.finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {

    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameView;
    TextView bioView;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    TextView badge;
    ProgressBar idleTimeBar;
    public ImageView eyeView;
    ImageView instagramVerified;
    RelativeLayout badgeBg;
    ImageView solOk;
    TextView tarihText;
    ImageView fotoIcon;
    ImageView sesIcon;
}


public static class ConversationsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Conversation> conversations;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    private ConversationsAdapter(Context context, List<Conversation> conversations) {
        this.conversations = conversations;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void updateConversations(List<Conversation> conversations) {
        this.conversations = conversations;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return conversations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Conversation getItem(int position) {
        return conversations.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_bars_v2, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            holder.badge = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unreadMessageCount);
            holder.bioView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bioText);
            holder.imageView = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.badgeBg = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unreadMessageBg);
            holder.solOk = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
            holder.tarihText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
            holder.sesIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Conversation item = conversations.get(position);
        String name = item.getName();
        String image_url = "http://application.domain.com/photos/profile/main/" + item.getPicture();

        if (item.getLastMessage().equals("Fotoğraf")) {
            holder.sesIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.send_photo);
            holder.sesIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (item.getLastMessage().equals("Ses")) {
            holder.sesIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.send_voice_record);
            holder.sesIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.sesIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        Long messageTimestamp = item.getLastMessageTime();

        long nowTimestamp = timeHolder.toMillis(false);


        Calendar messageTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar currentTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        messageTimeCal.setTimeInMillis(messageTimestamp);
        currentTimeCal.setTimeInMillis(nowTimestamp);

        boolean sameDay = messageTimeCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == currentTimeCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
                messageTimeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == currentTimeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        boolean lastDay = messageTimeCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == currentTimeCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) -1 &&
                messageTimeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == currentTimeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        String dateText = "";
        if (sameDay) {
            //Mesaj bugün mü gönderildi?
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            dateText = dateFormat1.format(messageTimeCal.getTime());
        }else{
            if (lastDay) {
                //Bugün değilse mesaj dün mü gönderilmiş?
                dateText = "Dün";
            }else{
                //Dün de değilse kaç gün önce gönderilmiş?
                long diff = Math.abs(nowTimestamp - messageTimestamp);
                int bolum =  (int) (diff / (24 * 60  * 60 * 1000));
                if (bolum <= 3) {
                    //Eğer geçen gün sayısı 3 veya daha az ise gün adını ekrana yaz
                    dateText = String.format("%tA", messageTimeCal);
                }else{
                    //Yoksa direk tarihi yaz
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    dateText = dateFormat.format(messageTimeCal.getTime());
                }
            }
        }




        holder.tarihText.setText(dateText);


        holder.nameView.setText(name);
        if (item.getLastMessageFromMe() == 0) {
            holder.bioView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A7A7A"));
            //holder.solOk.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#666666"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); -- mehmet değiştirdi
            holder.bioView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
        } else {
            holder.bioView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7A7A7A"));
            //holder.solOk.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#A8A8B7"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY); -- mehmet değiştirdi
            holder.bioView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
        holder.bioView.setText(item.getLastMessage());
        if (item.getLastMessage().equals("")) {
            holder.bioView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.bioView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (item.getPicture().equals("default.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_picture).into(holder.imageView);
        }else if (item.getPicture().equals("default_1.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_color_1).into(holder.imageView);
        }else if (item.getPicture().equals("default_2.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_color_2).into(holder.imageView);
        }else if (item.getPicture().equals("default_3.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_color_3).into(holder.imageView);
        }else if (item.getPicture().equals("default_4.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_color_4).into(holder.imageView);
        }else if (item.getPicture().equals("default_5.jpg")) {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.default_color_5).into(holder.imageView);
        }else{
            Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(holder.imageView);
        }

        holder.badge.setText(String.valueOf(item.getUnread()));
        if (item.getUnread() != 0) {
            holder.badgeBg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.badgeBg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Listview xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/conversationList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="7.0sp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/conversations_selector"></ListView>
```

How can i achive that functionality?

Comment: Can you add the `ConversationAdapter` class? At least  `ViewHolder`, `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` . I can be more precise if you do so. The idea is to add a field in the  `ViewHolder` that says "the item is now selected"! If you post that part I can answer more precisely :-)

Comment: @A.Wolf see my edit please :)

Comment: Thank you for your edit! Now I'm at work, I can't answer in a good way right now, I'm sorry. I'll post a correct answer in the afternoon or this evening :) The idea is dealing with `RecyclerView`. I will post the code as complete as possible, now I can't try it to be sure it works in the proper way.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I am waiting your code :)

Comment: Your welcome! I would answer right now, but I can't :-P

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test the code this evening; I provide you a possible solution (I don't know if works or not, I'm sorry). In the next days I will try to improve it, because I know it's not enough specific. Probably I will ask you more details to understand what behaviour you want. I wish that the answer can help you a little bit in the meanwhile :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a field `conversationSelected` in the `Conversation` class.
You should use`RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.
You can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to get started with `RecyclerView`.
When you have your `RecyclerView`, you can define the `Adapter` in this way:

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConversationAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<Conversation> conversations;

public ConversationAdapter(List<Conversation> conversations) {
    this.conversations = conversations; 
}

public ConversationAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
    ...
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Conversation conversation = conversations.get(position);
holder.mTextView.setText(conversation.getConversationText());   

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return conversations.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}
```

Next step: add item click listener to the `RecyclerView`: I struggled a little bit before see this answer which helps me to solve the problem: [RecyclerView click Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304517/2993413)

In the clickListener you have to change the state `conversationSelected` of the `Conversation` in the `conversations` list (not inside the `ViewHolder`) to `true`.
Then when you need to retrieve the selected conversation you have only to check this value.