# Need to pass recyclerview clicked item id to second recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android app.

There is an activity with two independent recyclerviews.

The first one is horizontal and has its own adapter.
The second one is vertical and has also its own adapter.

The first time the activity is started, both recyclerviews show all items from their respective sources.

But later I need to filter the items to be shown on the second recycler view depending on the selected item from the first recyclerview.

At the first adapter, when an item is clicked I get the id from it, which I could use to filter the items from the second recyclerview.

Which is the best way to pass the id from the first recyclerview clicked item to the second recyclerview with no need to reload the activity?

[image]

Here is the way I am getting the id from the first adapter:

```
class MenuClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
            Integer pos;

            public MenuClickListener(int pos) {
                this.pos = pos;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favourite:


                        String positi = marcaList.get(pos).getnombre();
                        Integer positid = marcaList.get(pos).getId();


                        return true;

                    default:
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Both recyclerviews are populated from a remote database.

EDIT

FRAGMENT CODE

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "https://.../Api.php";


    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    //a list to store all the products
    List<Marca> marcaList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    public List<Dispositivo> dispositivos;


    EditText cadenaNf,cadenaCf;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayout;
    private DispositivoAdapter adapter;


    private Button botonbuscar;

    private String cadenaC,cadenaN;


    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }





    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerMarcas);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        marcaList = new ArrayList<>();
        loadProducts();


        // SwipeRefreshLayout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
              //  dispositivos.clear();
                // Fetching data from server
               // getDispositivosFromDB(0);
            }
        });


        cadenaNf = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cadenaNtxt);

        cadenaNf.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ANTES DE ESCRIBIR CADENA N "+ charSequence);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ESCRIBIENDO CADENA N "+ charSequence);

                if(charSequence.length() >3 ){
                    dispositivos.clear();

                    getDispositivosBusquedaFromDB(0, charSequence.toString());
                }
                if(charSequence.length()== 0 ){
                    dispositivos.clear();
                    getDispositivosFromDB(0);
                }



                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search submit N FFF CHANGE "+ charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                dispositivos.clear();
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search submit N FFF "+editable );
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ENVIADA CADENA N "+ editable);
            }
        });
        cadenaCf = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cadenaCtxt);
        cadenaCf.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ANTES DE ESCRIBIR CADENA C "+ charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ESCRIBIENDO CADENA C "+ charSequence);
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search submit N FFF CHANGE "+ charSequence);
                if(charSequence.length() >3 ){
                    dispositivos.clear();

                    getDispositivosBusquedaFromDB(0, charSequence.toString());
                }
                if(charSequence.length()== 0 ){
                    dispositivos.clear();
                    getDispositivosFromDB(0);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                dispositivos.clear();
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search submit CCC FFF "+editable );
                Log.d("SEARCH string", "pulsado search ENVIADA CADENA C "+ editable);
            }
        });







        // getData();





        recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        dispositivos = new ArrayList<>();


        gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);

        adapter = new DispositivoAdapter(getActivity(), dispositivos);
        dispositivos.clear();

        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter);




        getDispositivosFromDB(0);

        return v;

    }

    private void getDispositivosBusquedaFromDB(int id, final String busqueda) {

        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA ESTOY BUSCANDO: "+busqueda);

        dispositivos.clear();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        Log.d("estoy en directorio= ",busqueda);

        Log.d("Texto buscado= ",busqueda);
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {

                String URL = "https://._busca.php?id="+busqueda;
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.d("Texto buscado=estoy ",busqueda);
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Log.d("Texto buscado loop= ",busqueda);
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Dispositivo dispositivo = new Dispositivo(object.getInt("id_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("usuario_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("fecha_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("precio_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("garantia"),
                                object.getString("estado"),
                                object.getString("estado_publicacion"),
                                object.getString("localizacion"),
                                object.getString("comentarios"),
                                object.getString("modelo_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("foto_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("foto2"),
                                object.getString("foto3"),
                                object.getString("foto4"),
                                object.getString("foto5"),
                                object.getString("hora_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("modelo_del_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("logo_marca")


                        );

                        dispositivos.add(dispositivo);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


                recyclerView1.swapAdapter(adapter, true);

                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }


    private void getDispositivosFromDB(int id) {
        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA SIN BUSCAR: ");

        dispositivos.clear();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
                //  Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);
```

//******** HERE I NEED THE ID RECEIVED FROM ADAPTER 1 
// String id = (id received from adapter1)

```
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url("...todos.php?id="+id)
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA busqueda: " + i);
                        Log.d("DISPOSITIVOS", "DISPOSITIVO: " + object);
                        Dispositivo dispositivo = new Dispositivo(object.getInt("id_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("usuario_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("fecha_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("precio_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("garantia"),
                                object.getString("estado"),
                                object.getString("estado_publicacion"),
                                object.getString("localizacion"),
                                object.getString("comentarios"),
                                object.getString("modelo_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("foto_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("foto2"),
                                object.getString("foto3"),
                                object.getString("foto4"),
                                object.getString("foto5"),
                                object.getString("hora_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("modelo_del_dispositivo"),
                                object.getString("logo_marca")
                        );

                        dispositivos.add(dispositivo);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }


    private void loadProducts() {

        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 valor=" + response);
                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject marca = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                marcaList.add(new Marca(
                                        marca.getInt("id"),
                                        marca.getString("nombre"),

                                        marca.getString("icono")
                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            MarcasAdapter adapter = new MarcasAdapter(getActivity(), marcaList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        dispositivos.clear();
        getDispositivosFromDB(0);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "BUSCANDO ONCREATEA CCAA:ONRESUME ANTES DE CLEAR ");


        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "BUSCANDO ONCREATEA CCAA:ONRESUME DESPUES DE CLEAR ");
        // Set title bar
        ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                .setActionBarTitle("Portada de Jogua");

    }
}
```

ADAPTER 1 CODE MarcasAdapter

```
public class MarcasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarcasAdapter.ProductViewHolder>  {


    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Marca> marcaList;
    private SharedPreferences mPref;
    public MarcasAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Marca> marcaList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.marcaList = marcaList;
    }




    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marcas_list, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Marca marca = marcaList.get(position);
String url = "https://jogua.es/administrar/application/admin/iconos/";
        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(url+marca.geticono())
                .into(holder.imageView);





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return marcaList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textViewTitle;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            showPopupMenu(v, position);

            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 valor=" + position);
        }

        private void showPopupMenu(View view, int poaition) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context_directorio, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuClickListener(poaition));
            popup.show();
        }

        class MenuClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
            Integer pos;

            public MenuClickListener(int pos) {
                this.pos = pos;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favourite:


                        String positi = marcaList.get(pos).getnombre();
                        Integer positid = marcaList.get(pos).getId();


                        return true;

                    default:
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ADAPTER 2 CODE DispositivosAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.mpidesarrollo.jogua.R;

import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class DispositivoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DispositivoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Dispositivo> dispositivos;
    private String emailsegundo;

    private SharedPreferences mPref;
    private  static final String PREF_NAME = "dispositivo";

    private static final String BACK_STACK_ROOT_TAG = "detalle_disp";

    public DispositivoAdapter(Context context, List<Dispositivo> dispositivos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dispositivos = dispositivos;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dispositivo_card,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.txtnombre.setText(dispositivos.get(position).getmodelo_del_dispositivo());

        String precio = dispositivos.get(position).getprecio_dispositivo().toString();
        String newString = precio.replace(".", ",");


        holder.txtPrecio.setText(newString+" €");

        String url_foto = "https://jogua.es/administrar/application/admin/dispositivos/"+dispositivos.get(position).getfoto_dispositivo();
        Glide.with(context).load(url_foto).into(holder.imageView);

        String url_logoMarca = "https://jogua.es/administrar/application/admin/iconos/"+dispositivos.get(position).getlogo_marca();
        Glide.with(context).load(url_logoMarca).into(holder.logoMarca);


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dispositivos.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{



        public TextView txtnombre,txtPrecio;



        public ImageView imageView;
        public ImageView logoMarca;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtnombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
            txtPrecio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio);
           imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            logoMarca = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.logoMarca);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();

            Log.d("DISPOSITIVO", "dispositivo pulsado"+position );

            editor.putInt("ID_DISPOSITIVO", dispositivos.get(position).getid_dispositivo());
            editor.putString("FOTO_DISPOSITIVO", dispositivos.get(position).getfoto_dispositivo());
            editor.putString("FOTO2", dispositivos.get(position).getfoto2());
            editor.putString("FOTO3", dispositivos.get(position).getfoto3());
            editor.putString("FOTO4", dispositivos.get(position).getfoto4());
            editor.putString("FOTO5", dispositivos.get(position).getfoto5());

            editor.apply();

            DetalleDispositivoFragment firstFragment = new DetalleDispositivoFragment();
            ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(BACK_STACK_ROOT_TAG)

                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, firstFragment).commit();
            //showPopupMenu(v,position);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Create refresh fun(public) in second adapter and pass id and filter data or reload again only for that adapter by using `notifyDataSetChanged(...)`. You can access refresh method from activity any time

Comment: pass an id to `adapter` and refill your `list` and `notifyadapter()`

Comment: @MD, thank you, but I don't understand your proposal

Comment: can you show me your adapters?

Comment: Get item id from first list and  filter the second list according to that ID and then send filtered list to the second adapter or notify the adapter .

Comment: use interface get the item id and pass the item to the second list and update the second adapter

Comment: @mvasco It's quite difficult to give 100 % right answer without checking your code.I posted the way now it's depend on how you made code

Comment: @MD, what do you need from my code?

Comment: @MD, to populate the recyclerviews I am using async calls to a web service, what I need is to pass the id from the first recyclerview clicked (from adapter 1) item to the method that is making the call to the web service from the activity

Comment: @MD, code included in the question

Comment: @TalhaBilal, that should be the process, but I don't know how to pass the id from first list to the activity that should filter the items from second adapter depending on that id

Comment: @mvasco we will not give the proper answer until you share the code . 
 we can just tell procedure without seeing your code .

Comment: @TalhaBilal, I have included the code for the second recyclerview? Do you need more code? Then tell exactly what you need and I will include it...

Comment: yes your activity code  as well as both adapter .

Comment: @TalhaBilal, all code included. Thank you

Comment: @mvasco see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304517/6762459) .
this will tell you how to get item position from recyclerView's Adapter .
Once you get position then you can easily get ID too . 
Like List.get(position).getID()

Comment: @TalhaBilal, I am able to get the item position, as you may see in adapters1 code: Integer positid = marcaList.get(pos).getId(); What I need is to pass this id back to the fragment to filter items from second recyclerview

Comment: @mvasco add a public function with name filterList(int id) in your second adapter and do your function definition as you want . Once you done with you filter in this function just add the line `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end .
  `Integer positid = marcaList.get(pos).getId();`  
`secondAdapter.filterList(positid);`

Answer (score 1):

```
class MenuClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        Integer pos;

        public MenuClickListener(int pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_favourite:


                    String positi = marcaList.get(pos).getnombre();
                    Integer positid = marcaList.get(pos).getId();
                    // do network operation here
                    // Eg: arraylist = api.getMobile(positid);
                    // update vertical recyclerview's data here
                    // verticalAdapter = new  VerticalAdapter(arraylist);

                    return true;

                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but I need to execute the method to load the filtered items from second adapter, that  is on the activity not in the adapter

Comment: post the initial call block

Answer (score 1):

When the first recycler view item is clicked, pass the corresponding id or information to another method (ex: setSecondRV(id OR information)).In this method, you can do network operation or normal operation to get your desired list. Then set the second recycler view by passing the list to the second adapter.
Don't forget to notify Adapter (secondAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();)

here is the link for a news app, which does network operation for second recycler view as per the first recycler view item clicked.

[NewsUltimate](https://github.com/prafulnayak/NewsUltimate)

Comment: Your app does exactly what I need, but I don't get where are you doing the network  operation needed

Comment: in adapter. You can do it in Activity as well.