# Attach click listener to each component of recycler view items

Tags: android

I am learning Android Development. Struggling with this issue since 24 hours, need help.

On my each recycle view item I've two views ePaper & Website. I want to attach different on click listeners on the entire item, ePaper view and website view

[image]

In the above image, I need to put 3 click listeners 
1. Click on red block 1 - do X (Intent to another activity)
2. Click on red block 2 - do Y (Intent to another activity)
3. Click on green block, entire item view - do Z (Dialog)

Tried many solutions. But, when I click red block, the listener in green block also comes to action in addition to listener in red block.

In the MainActivity

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(),
            recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        String userid = Utils.getUserId(getApplicationContext());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            // Set listeners here for complete card view
            final NewsPapersDataModel currentPaper = newsPapersList.get(position);
            Log.d("TAG","Clicked 1");

                newsSelectionDialog(currentPaper.getEpaper(),currentPaper.getWebsite());
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long press on position :" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }));
```

In the NewsPaperAdapter

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //  Log.d("TAG","Holder is "+newsList);

    final NewsPapersDataModel currentItem = newsList.get(position);
    final String ePaperUrl = currentItem.getEpaper();
    final String webSiteUrl = currentItem.getWebsite();
    final String paperName = currentItem.getName();

    holder.paperNameView.setText(newsList.get(position).getName());

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(currentItem.getEpaper())) {
        //  Log.d("TAGG","ePaper - "+currentItem.getEpaper()+" Website - "+currentItem.getWebsite());
        holder.ePaperView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(currentItem.getWebsite())) {
        holder.websiteView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    holder.ePaperView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            saveLinksToDb(userid, "ePaper", ePaperUrl);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsAdvancedWebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", ePaperUrl);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    holder.websiteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            saveLinksToDb(userid, "Website", webSiteUrl);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsAdvancedWebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", webSiteUrl);
            intent.putExtra("paperName",paperName);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

Please help me.

Comment: why are you adding touch listener to recycler view?

Comment: Check the Accepted answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `TouchListener` from MainActivity and add `ClickListener`/ `LonCkickListener` inside your adapter.

```
onBindViewHolder(){
    //rest of your code

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // Click implementation here
        }
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view) {
           // Long click implementation here
        }

    })
}
```

And inside your `CustomViewHolder`:

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    // Other fields

    View itemView;
    public CustomViewHolder(View view){
    // rest of initialization

    itemView = view;
    }
}
```

> **EDIT** (OP wants to handle application logic inside Activity)

Create an interface class named `RecyclerViewActionListener`:

```
public interface RecyclerViewActionListener {
    void onViewClicked(int clickedViewId, int clickedItemPosition);
    void onViewLongClicked(int clickedViewId, int clickedItemPosition);
}
```

Then modify your `RecyclerViewAdpater` to have an additional field in constructor. We will pass listener from Activity to this adpater when we create Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdpater.CustomViewHolder>{

    private RecyclerViewActionListener mListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdpater(ArrayList<Object> yourData,RecyclerViewActionListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false );
        final CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

        holder.webView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.onViewClicked(view.getId(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.paperView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.onViewClicked(view.getId(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.onViewClicked(view.getId(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                mListener.onViewLongClicked(view.getId(), holder.getAdapterPosition());
                return false;
            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        // Other fields

        View itemView;
        View webView;
        View paperView;
        public CustomViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            // rest of initialization

            itemView = view;
        }
    }
}
```

And then implement `RecyclerViewActionListener` in your Activity and override methods from `RecyclerViewActionListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewActionListener {


    RecyclerViewAdpater adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        // Skipped for the sake of brevity
        // Pass your listener to adapter here
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdpater(yourData, this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewClicked(int clickedViewId, int clickedItemPosition) {
        switch (clickedItemPosition){
            case R.id.web_view:
                // Application logic when webview clicked
                break;
            case R.id.paper_view:
                // Application logic when paperview clicked
                break;
            case R.id.recyclerview_item:
                // Application logic when whole item clicked
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewLongClicked(int clickedViewId, int clickedItemPosition) {
        switch (clickedViewId){
            case R.id.recyclerview_item:
                // Application logic when whole item long-clicked
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your xml file don't forget to assign ID to you views. Because we're detecting clicked view with their IDs.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/paper_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. This helped me to achieve what I desired. However, I read at some posts that adding click listeners in adapter is not a good practice. It should be done in the activity. Can you enlighten on this please.

Comment: do not use onlick on the bindview() it is bad for memory

Comment: follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0

Comment: @PradeepBehera, check the edited answer, please

Comment: Thank you @Farid , I'll try this tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an interface in your adapter for click listeners and add onclick methods for every item you want.

Please look into the code below.

In your adapter, create interface

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onPaperViewClick(View view, int position);
    void onWebsiteViewClick(View view, int position);
}
```

And create method to set click listener from activity

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    this.onClickListener= listener;
}
```

And in your *onBindViewHolder* method,

```
holder.ePaperView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        onClickListener.onPaperViewClick(view, position);
});

holder.websiteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        onClickListener.onWebsiteViewClick(view, position);
});
```

and lastly, in your activity, set

```
recyclerViewAdapter.setOnClickListener(new NewsPaperAdapter.OnClickListener(){
    @override
    void onPaperViewClick(View view, int position){
         // code to handle paper click
    }

    @override
    void onPaperViewClick(View view, int position){
        // code to handle website click
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try in your `NewsPaperAdapter` class `onClickListner` to parent layout of adapter like below

```
holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         final NewsPapersDataModel currentPaper = newsPapersList.get(position);
            Log.d("TAG","Clicked 1");

                newsSelectionDialog(currentPaper.getEpaper(),currentPaper.getWebsite());
        }
    });
```

here `parentLayout` is your adapter item layout root view like `Relative/Linear Layout`