# How to fetch data related to a clicked item in a recyclerView from room database to a new activity?

Tags: android, database, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-room

My app has a RawMaterialFragment that displays raw materials data in a recyclerView from room database.

I am trying to build a detail activity(MetrialItemView) to show up the details of an individual raw material by clicking or selecting the raw material from the recyclerView.

my problem is how to send the data from the adapter and how to receive the data in the MetrialItemView Activity and display it.

MaterialListAdapter:

```
public class MaterialListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MaterialListAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private FragmentRawMaterials mContext;
    private List<RawMaterialsEntity> mMaterial; // Cached copy of Materials
    RawMaterialsEntity mCurrent;


    public MaterialListAdapter(FragmentRawMaterials context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getActivity());
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView materialName;
        private final TextView materialBrand;
        private final TextView materialQuantity;
        LinearLayout parentLayout;


        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            materialName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.raw_material_name);
            materialBrand = itemView.findViewById(R.id.raw_material_brand);
            materialQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.raw_material_quantity);

            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (mMaterial != null) {
            mCurrent = mMaterial.get(position);
            holder.materialName.setText(mCurrent.getRawMaterialName());
            holder.materialBrand.setText(mCurrent.getRawMaterialBrand());
            holder.materialQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrent.getRawMaterialQuantity()));

        } else {
            // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
            holder.materialName.setText("Name NA");
            holder.materialBrand.setText("Brand NA");
            holder.materialQuantity.setText("Quantity NA");
        }



       holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getContext(), MaterialItemView.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }


    public void setMaterial(List<RawMaterialsEntity> materials){
        mMaterial = materials;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
    // mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mMaterial != null)
            return mMaterial.size();
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

MaterialItemView:

```
public class MaterialItemView extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.material_item_view);

}
}
```

material_list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Raw Material Name:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/material_name_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Raw Material Brand:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/material_brand_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unit Weight:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2000"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="gm"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unit Cost:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="50"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cost per gm/ml:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0.1"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Available Quantity:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1000"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total Cost:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="50000"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Supplier Name:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pandah"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Supplier Email:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pandah@panadh.com"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Supplier Phone:"
            style="@style/OtherTextViews"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+966555699517"
            style="@style/OtherTextViewsBody"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentRawMaterials:

```
public class FragmentRawMaterials extends Fragment{

    private RawMaterialViewModel mMaterialViewModel;
    private static final int NEW_MATERIAL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_raw_materials, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Setup any handles to view objects here
        //FloatingActionButton fab to insert recipes
        TextView emptyViewText = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_raw__materials_view);
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_raw_materials);
        fab.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RawMaterialsEditor.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_MATERIAL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        //Decoration to add a line divider between recyclerView items
        DividerItemDecoration decoration =
                new DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity()),
                        R.drawable.border_line);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        final MaterialListAdapter adapter = new MaterialListAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Check if adapter list is empty, if so empty text view will appear.
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emptyViewText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    emptyViewText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        mMaterialViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(RawMaterialViewModel.class);
        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
        mMaterialViewModel.getAllMaterials().observe(this, adapter::setMaterial);

    }



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == NEW_MATERIAL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            RawMaterialsEntity material = new RawMaterialsEntity(data
                    .getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_NAME),
                    data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_BRAND),
                    Float.valueOf(data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_WEIGHT)),
                    Float.valueOf(data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_COST)),
                    Integer.valueOf(data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_QUANTITY)),
                    data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_S_NAME),
                    data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_S_EMAIL),
                    data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_S_PHONE),
                    data.getStringExtra(RawMaterialsEditor.EXTRA_REPLY_UOM));
            mMaterialViewModel.insertMaterial(material);
            mMaterialViewModel.costPerGm();
            mMaterialViewModel.totalCost();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.editor_insert_rm_failed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When the user taps on you item, your itemClickListener is called, in that method, retrieve the ID of the item that was clicked, pass that onto your activity, and have your second activity fetch the data based upon the ID. Don't attempt to pass the entire item or the actual data to display.

Comment: How do I retrieve the ID of the clicked item

Comment: Because when I put mCurrent.getID() in extra intent it gets me the ID of the last item in the recyclerView

Comment: There are [multiple SO questions/answers about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each row of dataModel() must have ID and then use **putExtra()** whan clicked It happens

```
 holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getContext(), MaterialItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID",mCurrent.getID());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and use **getIntent()** in detailActivity

```
int id =getIntent().getIntExtra("ID",-1);
```

and then get a row data in detail activity from database(viewModel)by ID and parse it

Comment: Thanks, getItem falls under which class?

Comment: I did thanks, now the ID goes smoothly to the next activity

Comment: Can you please help me in fetching the data in the MaterialItemView using ID. how can I use the viewmodel in this case?