# How do I get the selected position in a RecyclerView when clicked from from an adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working on an app and i want it to scroll to a particular position i clicked from an adapter into another activity like the Instagram way of checking the smaller picture in the profile fragment and scrolling to the exact position in the other activity, that is from smaller picture to big picture.

MyAdapterCode

```
public class DisplayDuetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DisplayDuetAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DisplayDuet> mDisplayDuet;

    public int position;

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public DisplayDuetAdapter(Context context, List<DisplayDuet> displayDuet){
        mContext = context;
        mDisplayDuet = displayDuet;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DisplayDuetAdapter.ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.duet_display_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new DisplayDuetAdapter.ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final DisplayDuetAdapter.ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {

        final DisplayDuet displayDuet = mDisplayDuet.get(i);

        //  Glide.with(mContext).load(displayDuet.getOriginalpics()).into(imageViewHolder.original_pic);

        Picasso.get().load(displayDuet.getOriginalpics()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageViewHolder.original_pic, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Picasso.get().load(displayDuet.getOriginalpics()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageViewHolder.original_pic);

            }
        });

        //   Glide.with(mContext).load(displayDuet.getPostimage()).into(imageViewHolder.post_pic);


        Picasso.get().load(displayDuet.getPostimage()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageViewHolder.post_pic, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Picasso.get().load(displayDuet.getPostimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageViewHolder.post_pic);

            }
        });

        imageViewHolder.setiItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DuetDisplayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", displayDuet.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", displayDuet.getPublisher());
                intent.putExtra("postduetid", displayDuet.getPostduetid());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDisplayDuet.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView post_pic, original_pic;

        IItemClickListener iItemClickListener;

        public void setiItemClickListener(IItemClickListener iItemClickListener) {
            this.iItemClickListener = iItemClickListener;
        }

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            post_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duet_pic_one);

            original_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duet_pic_two);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            iItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

And the other activity code:

```
public class DuetDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String postid, publisher, postduetid;

    private ImageView duet_close;

    int position = 2;

    private RecyclerView duet_show_recyclerView;
    private DuetShowAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<DisplayDuet> postList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duet_display);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        postid = intent.getStringExtra("postid");
        publisher = intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");
        postduetid = intent.getStringExtra("postduetid");

        duet_close = findViewById(R.id.close);

        duet_show_recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.duet_show_recyclerView);
        duet_show_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        duet_show_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new DuetShowAdapter(this, postList);
        duet_show_recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        duet_show_recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
        SnapHelper startSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        duet_show_recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
        startSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(duet_show_recyclerView);

        duet_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        readPost();
    }

    private void readPost(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DuetPics").child(postid);
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot getsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : getsnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        DisplayDuet displayDuet = snapshot.getValue(DisplayDuet.class);
                        postList.add(displayDuet);

                    }

                    Collections.reverse(postList);
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get clicked item and its position in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296708/get-clicked-item-and-its-position-in-recyclerview)

Comment: check this answer [get clicked item and its position-in recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304517/7630948)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to pass the clicked position from your DisplayDuetAdapter to your DuetDisplayActivity.

If that is the case then you can pass it by the intent.

so pass the pressed item position in the DisplayDuetAdapter like this:

```
  imageViewHolder.setiItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DuetDisplayActivity.class);
                //pass position like this
                intent.putExtra("position", i);
                intent.putExtra("postid", displayDuet.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", displayDuet.getPublisher());
                intent.putExtra("postduetid", displayDuet.getPostduetid());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And get the position in the DuetDisplayActivity like this:

```
private int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duet_display);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        postid = intent.getStringExtra("postid");
        publisher = intent.getStringExtra("publisherid");
        postduetid = intent.getStringExtra("postduetid");
        //get the passed position
        position = intent.getIntExtra("position");

        ............
        ............
```

**update:**

do this:

```
        //get the passed position
         position = intent.getIntExtra("position",0);
```

Comment: Thanks but i can't receive the position with intent in the other activity... it says position is a string not an int.