# Get List entry by clicking RecyclerView entry

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a bunch of entries in my RV. One entry is one *Product*. Those products are in a list of products. All of them have a barcode and a name:

```
List<Product>;

Product(barcode, name);
```

Now when I click on one of these entrys, I want to delete it. Therefore I have a function like this in class RecycleViewAdapter:

```
holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            BackendClient.getInstance().deleteProduct(this.product);

        }

    });
```

Now how do I get the *product* of the entry I clicked in my RecycleViewAdapter class?

Comment: ```Now how do I get the product of the entry I clicked in my RecycleViewAdapter class?``` Please elaborate this part.

Comment: @SujalKumar Every entry in my RV is another product in my list. To delete it, I need the list entry (=product) of the entry I clicked on.

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304517/9520315

Comment: Using this way you could get the position of the entry clicked and then can further get the required ```Product``` object.