# unable to understand onClick event for multiple CardViews inside RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I looked up for the possible solutions but I could not figure out how to apply them in my case.
I am using a RecyclerView to display several CardViews inside it. Initially all cards have white background and I want to change the background color when a card is touched. Each CardView displays a name and an id as described in 'MyCards' class :

```
    public class MyCards {
    private String sName;
    private int sId;
    private boolean sPresent;

    public String getName() {
        return this.sName;
    }

    public MyCards(String sName, int sId, boolean sPresent) {
        this.sName = sName;
        this.sId = sId;
        this.sPresent = sPresent;
    }

    public void setName(String t) {
        this.sName = t;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return sId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.sId = id;
    }

    public boolean isPresent() {
        return sPresent;
    }

    public void setPresent(boolean present) {
        this.sPresent = present;
    }
}
```

I am making an ArrayList of these MyCards object in the 'Roster' class :

```
public class Roster extends ActionBarActivity{
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
private static final String TAG = null;
private RecyclerView rObject;
private MyAdapter adapter;
String abc = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.roster_recycle);
        rObject = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rObject.setLayoutManager(llm);

        MyCards c1 = new MyCards("Abhinav", 123, true);
        MyCards c2 = new MyCards("Abhishek", 13, false);
        performFileSearch();
        c1.setName("Abhinav");
        c2.setName("Baba");
        List<MyCards> cardList = new ArrayList<MyCards>();
        cardList.add(c1);
        cardList.add(c2);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(Roster.this,cardList);
        rObject.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The CardView is defined in the item_layout.xml file :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="contact det"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sPresent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/sId"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Present"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My question is : If I click on a card displaying data for 'c1' object then how can I identify that it was from 'c1' and not 'c2'. How do I use click handler in such cases where we display multiple cards?

I'm sorry if my question is too basic but I'm really stuck at it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? and How RecyclerView is different from Listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much for your responses, they really helped. Finally I found a video on YouTube which explained the concept in a nice manner. I am posting the link so that others can also benefit if they get stuck. Here is the video -

see this :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zE1E1HOK_E4

Comment: must watch if you want to delete item inside recyclerview !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif) answer for using an onItemClickListener with a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context mContext;
ArrayList<MyCard> mData;

public MyAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<MyCard> data ) {

    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView sName, sId , sPresent;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sName);
        sId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sId);
        sPresent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sPresent);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // your logic

            }
        });
    }

}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout , parent , false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final MyCard card = mData.get(position);
    holder.sName.setText(card.getName().toString());
    holder.sId.setText(card.getId().toString());
    holder.sPresent.setText(card.getPresent().toString());

}
```

}

Comment: extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>