# Android RecyclerView OnClickListener not reacting

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Ok, so I'm using RecyclerView in my project and need to implement click listener for each list item and an icon in each of the items.

What I tried was this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/722462 cause it looks pretty nice for me. But I couldn't get click listener to react for any click events. Any ideas what is wrong with my implementation? All the files listed below.

fragment_search.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/search_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/icon_search_empty"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_48dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Brak wyników wyszukiwania"
            android:id="@+id/text_search_empty" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_station_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_item_station_fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_blue_24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:tint="#E3F2FD"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_station_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingLeft="58dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finaly SearchAdapter.java:

```
    public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<StationDTO> stations;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView stationName;
        public ImageView favIcon;

        private IHasSearchViewHolderCallback hasSearchViewHolderCallback;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, IHasSearchViewHolderCallback hasSearchViewHolderCallback) {
            super(itemView);

            this.hasSearchViewHolderCallback = hasSearchViewHolderCallback;

            favIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_item_station_fav);
            stationName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_station_name);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            favIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

            Context ctx = itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
            FontHelper.ROBOTO_REGULAR.on(ctx, stationName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.item_station_layout:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onItemLayout(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.icon_item_station_fav:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onFavIcon(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.item_station_name:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onStationName(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
            }
        }

        public interface IHasSearchViewHolderCallback {
            void onItemLayout(int position);
            void onFavIcon(int position);
            void onStationName(int position);
        }
    }

    public SearchAdapter(List<StationDTO> stations) {
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View item = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_station, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(item, new ViewHolder.IHasSearchViewHolderCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLayout(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "LAYOUT #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFavIcon(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "FAV #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStationName(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "NAME #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        StationDTO dto = stations.get(position);

        holder.stationName.setText(dto.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a listener for your image view.  But is it not firing even if you tap on your text view?

Comment: In fact I was missing listener for TextView, which as turned out is covering all the parent view and is over ImageView so it was intercepting all the events. So problem solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.item_station_layout:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onItemLayout(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.icon_item_station_fav:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onFavIcon(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.item_station_name:
                    hasSearchViewHolderCallback.onStationName(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
            }
        }
```

to

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // appropriate code in here
    }
});
```

and do the same for favIcon. I have a feeling your problem is arising from the fact that your OnClickListener is on your ViewHolder and not actually on the TextView and ImageView.