# How to get other views in same ViewHolder at same position as the onClicked view (use in a RecyclerView Adapter)

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my app that displays a row containing pictures and photographs downloaded from the internet. There is a photo and a button on screen. When the user clicks a button, I want to make another view visible on top of the on screen photo.

I have a CustomViewHolder that holds all the views for the RecyclerView and a CustomRecyclerViewAdapter that displays the viewholder views. The onClick method for the button is overridden in the CustomViewHolder as below -

```
public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
implements OnClickListener {

public Button mButton;
public ImageView mImageView1;
public ImageView mImageView2;

public CustomViewHolder(View v)
{
super(v);
mButton = (Button) ...           // Initializing views
mImageView1 = (ImageView) ...
mImageView2 = (ImageView) ...
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if(id == R.id.buttonid)
        {
             // TODO mImageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             // Any ideas on how to get the mImageView2 of this same item so it can be made visible?
        }
}
```

I need a way to get a reference of the mImageView2 view at the same position as the clicked button. Does anybody know how to do this? I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is implement `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position)` in your `Adapter`

This method already have position as a third argument.

### LIKE

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

     holder.mImageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: you CANNOT use the position in the callback because it may change. Instead, use ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition and also add the callback in onCreateViewHolder to avoid churning click listener objects.

See the documentation for details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH, int)

Comment: @yigit Ya i knew that one.. And i must tell you there are lots of ways to getting this. `If you have enough knowledge.`

Comment: This is not advised.  Read the first comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/29841832/4443323

Answer (score 0):

Try *getAdapterPosition* method of the ViewHolder. it will return the position of the Holder in the Recycler/Adapter