# Can't use getLayoutPosition() or getAdapterPosition() in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I really don't know why I can't use `getLayoutPosition();` or `getAdapterPosition();` methods inside my class.

```
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView price;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_list_image);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_list_title);
            price = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_list_price);
            image.setOnClickListener(this);
            title.setOnClickListener(this);
            price.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public ImageView getImage() {
            return image;
        }
        public TextView getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public TextView getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getLayoutPosition(); //no method like that
        }
    }
```

I can use however `getPosition()` but is deprecated and above methods are advised. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getLayoutPosition())

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951551/how-to-get-other-views-in-same-viewholder-at-same-position-as-the-onclicked-view/30951600#30951600](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951551/how-to-get-other-views-in-same-viewholder-at-same-position-as-the-onclicked-view/30951600#30951600)

Comment: which version of   support:recyclerview are you using ?

Comment: @Blackbelt `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`

Comment: yes got it. Check which reversion are you using. It is in your module build.gradle

Comment: @Blackbelt sorry, didn't understand what you mean. `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getLayoutPosition()` and `getAdapterPosition()` are part of revision 22 of the support library. You are not able to resolve it because you are still using rev 21. Change

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

to

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
```

sync gradle, and try again

Comment: so that was the case... I will remember the lesson.