# Custom Dialog Button called inside RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to have the OnClick of the Custom Dialog remove and update the item clicked from RecyclerView.

```
    final Dialog rightDialog = new Dialog(context1);
    ...
    TextView textOKRight = (TextView) rightDialog.findViewById(R.id.text_ok);
    textOKRight.setText("NEXT");
    textOKRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     // MainAdapter.ViewHolder ccd = new MainAdapter.ViewHolder(itemView, listener);
     // ccd.removeCaller();
        rightDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    rightDialog.show();
```

`MainAdapter`

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>{
..
   private static ViewHolder.IndividualClickListener mListenerCallback;
   private static ViewHolder.IndividualClickListener mListener;
   private MainAdapter mMyAdapter;
   public AnimatorSampleActivity animatorActivity;

public MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Question> dataSet) {
    mContext = context;
    questions = dataSet;
    ...
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  { 

    public IndividualClickListener mListener;
    ...

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, IndividualClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        mListener = listener;
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMic);
        imageOne = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageOne);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        image.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //////THIS IS THE METHOD I WOULD LIKE TO CALL FROM THE DIALOG///////
    public void removeCaller() {
        mListener.remove1(getLayoutPosition()); 
        Log.d(TAG, "Main Adapter Called remove1 from removeCaller()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v instanceof ImageView) {

        } else { 

        }

    }

    public interface IndividualClickListener {

        void onTomato(ImageView callerImage, int position);
        void onPotato(View caller, int position);
        void remove1(int position);
        void onDialogClick(TextView textOKRight); 

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questions.size();

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Question currentQuestion = questions.get(position);
 ///I CREATED A DIALOG HERE, Dialog.Builder AND IM ABLE TO HAVE THE DIALOG DIMISS AND REMOVE THE ITEM, BUT I CANT FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO IT FROM MY CUSTOM DIALOG OUTSIDE MainAdapter////
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentQuestion.drawableId).into(holder.getImageView());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(currentQuestion.iconId).into(holder.getImageView1());

    holder.getImageView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v instanceof ImageView) {
              //holder.removeCaller();
              //mAdapterCallback.remove1(position);
                mListenerCallback.onTomato((ImageView) v, position);
                Log.d(TAG, "Main Adapter Called remove from OnBindViewHolder"+""+position);

            }else{
                mListenerCallback.onPotato((ImageView) v, position);
            }
      }
});

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);

    final MainAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, new MainAdapter.ViewHolder.IndividualClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTomato(ImageView callerImage, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Main Adapter Called OnTomato OnCreateVIewHolder");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPotato(View caller, int position) {

        }
        @Override
        public void remove1(int position) {
            questions.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Main Adapter Called remove1 from OnCreaterViewHolder" + position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDialogClick(TextView textOKRight) {

        }


    });

    return vh;
}


public interface callerCallBack{
     .....

 }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class NewCustomDialog extends Dialog   {
private static dialogCallerCallBack mdialogCallerCallBack;
private MainAdapter.ViewHolder.IndividualClickListener listener;

public NewCustomDialog(Activity a, dialogCallerCallBack mdialogCallerCallBack, Context dContext, TextView dialogTitleRight, TextView rightMsgRight, TextView rightAnswerRight, TextView textOKRight, ImageView imageRight) {
    super(a);
    this.dialogTitleRight = dialogTitleRight;
    this.rightAnswerRight = rightAnswerRight;
    this.rightMsgRight = rightMsgRight;
    this.textOKRight = textOKRight;
    this.imageRight = imageRight;
    this.dContext = dContext;
    //pass this so it can be used
    this.mdialogCallerCallBack=mdialogCallerCallBack;

   this.c =a;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //final Dialog rightDialog = new Dialog(context);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mt_alert_right_dialog);
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    setCancelable(false);
    TextView dialogTitleRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    TextView rightMsgRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_msg);
    TextView rightAnswerRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right_answer);
    final TextView textOKRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_ok);
    ImageView imageRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    textOKRight.setText("NEXT");
    textOKRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mdialogCallerCallBack.onDialogClick(((TextView)textOKRight));

        }
    });
}


public interface dialogCallerCallBack{
    void onDialogClick(TextView textOKRight);
}
}
```

Error

```
Process: jp.wasabeef.example.recyclerview, PID: 28523
java.lang.NullPointerException at jp.wasabeef.example.recyclerview.NewCustomDialog$1.onClick(NewCustomDialog.java:82)
```

line 82 is

```
mdialogCallerCallBack.onDialogClick(((TextView)textOKRight));
```

Comment: Delegate the onClicks outside the adapter into your Activity or Fragment, and treat the dialog as another fragment. Do not handle their lifecycle inside other views. They're overcomplicated as they are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By "treat the adapter as another fragment" you mean I should inflate the custom dialog inside adapter, but handle the on click outside the adapter? updated question to see if I understood what you meant, with error and log..thanks again

Comment: >treat the dialog as another fragment -> Meaning handle it at activity level, not inside the adapter. One you have that, just follow Google's examples.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM Got it to work. Your comments on "view lifecycle handling", "overcomplicated" and "treating the dialog as a fragment", really helped me to take a new approach and perspective on my implementation and problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if your problem is using getFragmentManaget to implement do like below:
create

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

in your Fragment and pass it to your `RecyclerView` and again pass it to your `ViewHolder`

note: pass means send it as argument to constructor