# RecyclerView inside DialogFragment inside Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When I press a button in my `Activity`, a `DialogFragment` pops up. Inside the dialog fragment, there is a `RecyclerView` that looks a like a normal list view.

The behaviour I want is that when I press on row n of the `RecyclerView`, the `DialogFragment` closes and the `Activity` does something based on the value associated with row n.

It seems that the `ViewHolder` has to implement the `OnClickListener` interface. When a row is clicked, the `ViewHolder`'s delegate should do something. The delegate should be the `DialogFragment`. And the `DialogFragment` in turn talks with the `Activity` to which it is attached.

If this is the case, the `ViewHolder` has to ask the `DialogFragment` to do something, and the `DialogFragment` asks the `Activity` to do something. Is this the right approach? How do I pass the reference of the `DialogFragment` to `onCreateViewHolder()`? Should the `Adapter` keep a reference to the `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Please check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've checked that. But my case is different in that the recycler view is inside a fragment and it needs to talk with the activity. I want to know if my approach is right.

Comment: Try to work with interface, make an interface having one function onDialogItemClick, then implement it in activity and pass its reference to the adapter. Then call that method with that reference in adapter. And let your activity method do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are moving in the right direction. Pass the `DialogFragment`'s reference in the constructor of the adapter. Once you have the reference and the desired click event fires, call `getActivity()` on the dialog's reference to get a reference to the activity. Then you can do whatever you want in the activity. Also, I suggest you implement listeners using interfaces. What you want to do is keep the `DialogFragment` invisible to the underlying activity and your adapter loosely coupled to the `DialogFragment`, and interfaces will help in that case.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean that in `onCreateDialog`, I pass in `this` to the `Adapter`'s constructor?

Comment: That would be one way to do it. What you can also do is make your activity implement a listener interface, and pass your activity casted to the listener using ((Listener) getActivity()) instead of passing this (i.e the Dialog). That way you can directly call the activity from the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's always good to learn from alternatives. I think I will go for the pass-the-fragment approach, because in that way, the `DialogFragment` has a chance to close itself.