# Best practise to refreshing adapter data with custom view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have the following custom view:

`|--------------------|
|    [ ] TextView    |
|--------------------|`

This is just a simple `CheckBox` and a `TextView`. This `View` is shown multiple times (days in month), presented on the screen via a list (`RecylverView`).

For that I have a `Fragment` which will first read data from a database and then put this data into the list.

```
String[] data = getDataFromDB();
mRecycler.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(data));
```

Imagine that every other item has a checked `CheckBox`.
So we have (for example with 4 Items) a list like this:

`|--------------------|
|    [ ] TextView    |
|--------------------|
|--------------------|
|    [X] TextView    |
|--------------------|
|--------------------|
|    [ ] TextView    |
|--------------------|
|--------------------|
|    [X] TextView    |
|--------------------|`

The user can now check or uncheck the `CheckBox` (well, it is a checkbox :)). On programmer side the dataArray from the database must be updated too. Because, if I don't do so and the user scroll, the specific list-item should be created with the old data. Yeah, that is the recycler thing is for :)

Anyway. When the user check/uncheck I need to updated the data.
And here is my question: What is the best practice to do so?

One idea is to set an `Interface` in the adapter for each `View`, to be notified when something changes. Each `CheckBox` becomes a listener which will be called when the user clicks on a `CheckBox`. The listener received a notification (from the adapter) and it can update the data.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        myViewHolder.myView.setModel(data.get(position));
        myViewHolder.myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnChanged) {
            // TODO: Update data and refresh list/adapter
        }
    }

}
```

Another idea is to put the list and the data in a custom `View`.
The custom `View` implements the `CheckedChanceListener` and updates the database and list `Adapter`.

```
public class TimeTrackingCardView extends CardView {

    public void setListThings(String[] data, MyAdapter adapter) {
        myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnChanged) {
            // TODO: Update data and refresh list/adapter
        }
    }

}
```

Both ideas aren't very good. Any other ideas or patterns for refreshing `Adapter` data using custom `View`s?

Note:
This is a very basic custom `View`. My app actually has multiple `Views` (4 `Buttons` with text changes, 1 `CheckBox` and a `EditText`) but with the same idea.

Comment: You say the ideas aren't very good. Can you please explain it why?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif). The OnClick Probelm is very similar to your Problem. This post helped me a lot.

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the issue. The question is about the best way to manage the data that backs the `Adapter` upon `CheckBox` changes.

Comment: Yes, that is'n exactly the answer I've looked for. But that helps a little bit.