# Cannot resolve method setOnChildClickListener

Tags: java, android, arraylist, expandablelistview

Here is my whole activity code, if nessery I can post my xml as well.

```
public class Main_Activityextends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    List<ExpandableListViewAdapter.Item> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add(new ExpandableListViewAdapter.Item(ExpandableListViewAdapter.HEADER, "Terms of usage"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListViewAdapter.Item(ExpandableListViewAdapter.CHILD, "never eat"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListViewAdapter.Item(ExpandableListViewAdapter.CHILD, "bluhhhhh"));

    recyclerview.setAdapter(new ExpandableListViewAdapter(data));

     recyclerview.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            return true;
        }

    });
```

The code works perfectly without the `clickListener`, but I want an action to happen when clicking on a certain child of the array but right now it says `Cannot resolve method setOnChildClickListener(anonymous android.widget.ExpendableListView.OnChildClickListener)` although The `recycleView` is my `Adapter`, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your childview

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: Do you have a Toast or something to know that it wasn't fire?

Comment: No cause I can't run it because the following error occurs `Cannot resolve method setOnChildClickListener(anonymous android.widget.ExpendableListView.OnChildClickListener)`

Comment: in your `onCreate()` add this : `isChildSelectable(true);`

Comment: Well sorry for troubling but I don't actually know where to put this, would you care to be more specific?

Comment: in your `onCreate()` add this line : `recyclerview.isChildSelectable(true);`

Comment: That method cannot be resolved

Comment: Calling methods on a class doesn't magically add new methods if they cannot be resolved. Check my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simply, `RecyclerView` does not support an `OnChildClickListener` because it is not intended to be a direct one for one replacement for a `ListView`.

For a very good explanation of why, check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/4516144)

You should instead implement `View.OnClickListener` in your `ViewHolder` class like so:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Your view fields here

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        // Assign view fields

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask this so late but with your class now how can I call a specific child, because I have not found any way

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "call a specific child", but you can use `getAdapterPosition()` to find the index of the view that has been clicked on.