# Android OnClick in ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

How to implement `OnClickListener` on a `ListAdapter`? My data is coming from sqlite. I want to show half of the data in the first activity and the reamining in the second activty using `OnClickListener` in `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) interface and call [`setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) on your `ListView`.

If you're using `ListFragment` oder `ListActivity`, you could also override their `onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id)` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use set ItemClickListener on ListView with help of "setOnItemClickListener".
If you want to catch clicks in adapter, it will be better to use RecyclerView.
Example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2687734

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    adapter.get(position); //get your custom model
  }
});
```