# What is the difference between ListView, AbsListView and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am new to android development and I came across these 3 different options ListView, AbsListView and RecyclerView to create a List in android. What is the difference between these 3.

Comment: Have you googled it!

Comment: It was a legit question and there is no reason for down vote! 
I up voted it for you man.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `AbsListView` is an abstract class and can't be used as a `View` element in application layout, although you can use it as a `Base Class` to implement your own `View`.
Before Lollipop, there wasn’t `RecyclerView`, it was introduced as a part of Material Design. It introduced a new way of handling listeners.

You can read more in-depth explanation  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2466495)

Starting from Lollipop it is considered as good practice to use `RecyclerView` instead of deprecated `ListView`.

You can read how to use `RecyclerView` at [official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) given by google or use [this great tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html).