# Android recycler view item position

Tags: android-recyclerview, cardview

In my app I am showing a list of cards in a recycler view. The card view consists of two textviews and one imageview. Whenever the user clicks on the imageView of a cardview I need the position of the cardview. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code and what you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the position selected in a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682277/how-do-i-get-the-position-selected-in-a-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an OnClickListener for your ImageView inside your Adapter , from there you can get the position of current Item by using getAdapterPosition() method.
also you can see :

[Get position of clicked item in recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867145/get-the-position-of-clicked-item-on-recycler-view)

[How do I get the position selected in a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682277/how-do-i-get-the-position-selected-in-a-recyclerview)