# Show a DialogFragment from RecyclerView.ViewHolder extending class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having issues related to this question [Starting DialogFragment from a class extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889477/starting-dialogfragment-from-a-class-extending-recyclerview-viewholder) .

I have try the solution given and I'm facing an error with `getSupportFragmentManager()` method.

```
    Error:(147, 15) error: no suitable method found for 
    show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
    method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager)
    method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)
```

Comment: Can you share your code to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extends your dialog fragment class from  android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment and not from android.app.DialogFragment