# start Fragment from RecycleView Adapter Onclick

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-recyclerview

Hi I have A `RecycleView` `Adapter` and A button. I want that button to start a Fragment. I can start an activity but not a fragment. I have tried this `Onclick` method for my `Button`

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("event", events.get(getLayoutPosition()));
            Fragment fragment = new EditEventDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentMainDrawer,fragment).commit();
        }
```

But have error invoke null object (`contentMainDrawer`) is my Main activity content_layout.

Any help is much appreciate. The Fragment host recycle view is call from Mainactivity

Comment: Uhm, you are not supposed to use FragmentManager from the Fragment that you have just created. Replace this line  fragment.getFragmentManager() with just getFragmentManager() (or getSupportFragmentManager() depending on what kind of Fragment you are using)

Comment: thanks for yrs help but the code is inside the RecycleView adapter (not another activity or fragment)

Comment: Well, if you really need to do this this way, then you can do this: ((Activity) v.getContext).getFragmentManager(). But this is not really a good approach. What you could is to move onClick's handling to the parent class. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/1139527

Comment: can not seem use the ((Activity) v.getContext).getFragmentManager(). Move OnClick handling mean OnClick will be handled in the class that use the adapter? but it's hard to get the item in the click position?

Comment: I've written this really quick. I hope that this will give you the basic idea on how to do achieve it: https://gist.github.com/scana/8ced6d423c91142c36ea

Comment: thanks a lot. so where do we put the intereface public interface MyItemClickListener and the public void onClick(View v) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99297/discussion-between-scana-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Comment: Its better to make interface !

Comment: Many thanks for @scana. Spend lot of time help me create an interface and debugging. will post the answer for other who need

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for replace fragment

```
 Fragment fragment = new EditEventDetailFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentMainDrawer, fragment, "tag").commit();
```

if you are using this code inside adapter than replace `getActivity()` to `((Activity) context).`

Comment: thanks for your respond but the code is inside recycleView adapter can not call getActivity() or i dont know how to call getActivity()

Comment: I tried few time but this line is not working             FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(); cannot call the getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: replace getSupportFragmentManager to getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: I Got this line FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(); conflict because my fragment use support v4 (I still dont know whether to use app.fragment or support v4.fragment

Comment: and also cannot change getFragmentManager to getChildFragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found 2 answer that help whoever needed. The answer is to use the Activity that host the calling fragment. Many thanks @Mohit Suthar

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("event", events.get(getLayoutPosition()));
            Fragment fragment = new EditEventDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentMainDrawer, fragment, "tag").commit();
```