# Starting a fragment on RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've read multiple posts regarding it; but for my specific case, I can't seem to make it work. The fragment doesn't seem to be replaced when the view in the adapter is clicked.

**Related posts:**

[start Fragment from RecycleView Adapter Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527115/start-fragment-from-recycleview-adapter-onclick)

[how to open a different fragment on recyclerview OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984879/how-to-open-a-different-fragment-on-recyclerview-onclick)

**Here is my RecyclerView**

```
public class LocationFilterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationFilterAdapter.LocationFilterViewHolder> {
        public Context mActivity;
        @Override
        public LocationFilterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.profile_tab_become_a_host_basic_questions_location_filter_item, parent, false);
            mActivity = parent.getContext();
            return new LocationFilterAdapter.LocationFilterViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(LocationFilterViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bindView(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return LocationFilterFragment.RESULT_SIZE;
        }

        public class LocationFilterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView tvLocations;
            public LocationFilterViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvLocations = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilterLocations);
            }

            public void bindView(int position){
                final String output = LocationFilterFragment.STREET_NAME + ", " + LocationFilterFragment.CITY_NAME
                        +", " + LocationFilterFragment.STATE_NAME + ", " + LocationFilterFragment.COUNTRY_NAME;

                tvLocations.setText(output);

                tvLocations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText etStreet = (EditText) LocationFilterFragment.mView.findViewById(R.id.etStreetFilter);
                        etStreet.setText(output);


                        LocationFragment locationFragment = new LocationFragment();
                        locationFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        //Fragment will not start
                        ((AppCompatActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.progressFragment, new LocationFragment()).commit();


                    }
                });
            }
```

**Here is my LocationFragment (SupportFragment)**

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab_become_a_host_basic_questions_location_fragment, container, false);
        Log.d("fragment lifecycle", "OnCreateView");

        if(getArguments() != null){

            TextView tvStreet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStreet);
            tvStreet.setText(getArguments().getString("STREET_NAME"));

            TextView tvState = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvState);
            tvState.setText(getArguments().getString("STATE_NAME"));

            TextView tvCity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
            tvCity.setText(getArguments().getString("CITY_NAME"));

        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        view.findViewById(R.id.layoutStreet).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.progressFragment, new LocationFilterFragment()).addToBackStack("locationFragment").commit();
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.bContinue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.progressFragment, new MapFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.layoutTapInfo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.progressFragment, new LocationInfoFragment()).addToBackStack("locationFragment").commit();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing but, the way I did it was right. For some reason. my Android Studio was acting weird; when I rebuild my project, the code totally worked :)