# Issues in recyclerview with onclick event values passed from one activity to another activity based on url id

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

Actually my issue is when i am clicking on Recyclerview items it shows only that item data in next activity based upon using id.but there is no Onitemclick method in recyclerview and how to rectify this error any one can solve this error?

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Your> yourss;
    String Tag_id="category_id";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        LinearLayoutManager ll = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(ll);
        new JsonTask().execute();
    }

    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Your>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Your> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://yoursubshop.com/webservices/categories.php");
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                String finaljson = sb.toString();
                JSONObject firstobject = new JSONObject(finaljson);
                JSONArray firstarray = firstobject.getJSONArray("data");
                List<Your> yo = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < firstarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalobject = firstarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Your yos = new Your();
                    yos.category_id = finalobject.getString("Tag_id");
                    yos.category_name = finalobject.getString("category_name");
                    yo.add(yos);
                }
                return yo;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {

                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Your> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Rvadapter listAdapter = new Rvadapter(MainActivity.this, result);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
              recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new         Intent(MainActivity.this,SeconActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("data",Tag_id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class Rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Rvadapter.Myadapter> {
        List<Your> yours = Collections.emptyList();
        Context c;
        public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView id;
            TextView name;
            CardView cv;
            public Myadapter(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texts);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textsa);
                cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);

            }
        }
        public Rvadapter(Context c, List<Your> yours) {
            this.yours = yours;
            this.c = c;
        }
        @Override
        public Myadapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lists, parent, false);
            Myadapter m = new Myadapter(v);
            return m;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Myadapter holder, int position) {
            Your  y = yours.get(position);
            holder.id.setText(y.category_id);
            holder.name.setText(y.category_name);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return yours == null ? 0 : yours.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    }
   }
```

SecondActivity.java

```
    public class SeconActivity extends Activity 
    {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Shop> shops;
    String serverUrl = "http://yoursubshop.com/webservices/categories-shop.php?category=";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seocnd_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.secondmain);
        LinearLayoutManager ll = new LinearLayoutManager(SeconActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(ll);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        String serverUrlId = in.getStringExtra("data");
        serverUrl = serverUrl.concat(serverUrlId);
        new JsonTask().execute();
    }
    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Shop>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Shop> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                String finaljson = sb.toString();
                JSONObject firstobject = new JSONObject(finaljson);
                JSONArray firstarray = firstobject.getJSONArray("data");
                List<Shop> yo = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < firstarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalobject = firstarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Shop yos = new Shop();
                    yos.shop_id = finalobject.getString("shop_id");
                    yos.shop_name= finalobject.getString("shop_name");
                    yo.add(yos);
                }
                return yo;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {

                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Shop> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Rvadapter listAdapter = new Rvadapter(SeconActivity.this, result);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
    }

    public class Rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Rvadapter.Myadapter> {
        List<Shop> yours = Collections.emptyList();
        Context c;
        public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView id;
            TextView name;
            CardView cv;
            public Myadapter(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopt);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopr);
                cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);

            }
        }
        public Rvadapter(Context c, List<Shop> yours) {
            this.yours = yours;
            this.c = c;
        }
        @Override
        public Myadapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shopss, parent, false);
            Myadapter m = new Myadapter(v);
            return m;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Myadapter holder, int position) {
            Shop  y = yours.get(position);
            holder.id.setText(y.shop_id);
            holder.name.setText(y.shop_name);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return yours == null ? 0 : yours.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope you can start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

Comment: i cannt understand will u tell based upon my programme sir

Comment: You have cardview in your adapter right. Implement OnClickListener and set the listener. In the onClick method use the intent to move to next screen

Comment: If your question is how to navigate to next screen from recyclerview the above comment is my suggestion. If your question is different please let me know

Comment: my issue is when i am click on single item on list of items in recyclerview.that single item has some particular id in server json  based on that id.information is retrived from server and it display in next activity.

Comment: reply sir @Raghavendra

Comment: use getAdapterPosition() to get the position. i.e., CURRENT_POSITION = getAdapterPosition(); in onClick method remove the old initialization and try

Answer (score 0):

set click listener to your root view of item layout, I change your `onBindViewHolder()` method

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Myadapter holder, int position) {
            Shop  y = yours.get(position);
            holder.id.setText(y.shop_id);
            holder.name.setText(y.shop_name);

            holder.ROOT_VIEW.setTag(position); // here ROOT_VIEW is your inflated layout root 
            holder.ROOT_VIEW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = (int) v.getTag(); // use this pos to get this perticular view related data
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SeconActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("data",Tag_id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
```

declare ROOT_VIEW in your holder class, get tag_id by pos from your list or what u have

Comment: how can i declare root view in method

Comment: same as u declare  holder.name, root_view means container layout of yout item layout it may be Linearlayout or RelativeLayout or any

Comment: its top most view of your R.layout.shopss file

Comment: i cant understand what is root view where i declare root view please give me some calrity

Comment: what is top layout of your shopss.xml layout file

Comment: Second_main layout is top layout then how can i write will u ellobrate that programme

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Rvadapter.Myadapter> implements View.OnClicklistener{
        List<Your> yours = Collections.emptyList();
        Context c;
        public class My
        private int CURRENT_POSITION = 0;

        public class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

            TextView id;
            TextView name;
            CardView cv;
            public Myadapter(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texts);
                name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textsa);
                cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
                cv.setOnClicklistener(this);
            }
        }


        ...

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Myadapter holder, int position) {
        CURRENT_POSITION = position;
        ...
        //your code
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

                Your y = yours.get(CURRENT_POSITION);
                if(y != null){}
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, ,SeconActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", y.category_id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
        }

        ...
        //your code
}
```

In the second activity get the category id from the intent and get the details from it.

Comment: it shows first position in recycler view item data only for every items present in recyclerview same data dispaly

Comment: it shows different data for diifferent id s it shows not based on id what is error

Comment: @A.asha use getAdapterPosition() to get the position. i.e., CURRENT_POSITION = getAdapterPosition(); in onClick method remove the old initialization and try

Comment: thanq but how do u know all this methods exactly in that place using

Comment: can i know what is the secret

Comment: yes worked but how would we know to write exactly that method in that place

Comment: @A.asha I have faced the same error once. At that time I have fixed it like this that's it