# RecyclerView onClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

So after 5 months of webdevelopment I needed to get back into android but I noticed some of my old code isn't working anymore. I have a RecyclerView with a adapter for the data but the onClickListener for the items doesn't respond to anything. This is what my code looks like:

```
public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Project> itemsData;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public ProjectAdapter(List<Project> itemsData) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new views
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


        viewHolder.txtViewId.setText(String.valueOf(itemsData.get(position).getId()));
        viewHolder.txtViewName.setText(itemsData.get(position).getName());


    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView txtViewName, txtViewId;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            txtViewId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("onClick");
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            String id = tv.getText().toString();
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), id); //OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position, String id);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.size();
    }
}
```

ProjectsActivity.java

```
projectAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new ProjectAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position, String id) {
        System.out.println("onItemClick" + id);
        ActionActivity(id);
    }
});
```

The list gets showed, the click doesn't work, not even the log to the console.
Does anybody know what I've been doing wrong? I'm using SDK v23 as the compile sdk version. My minimum SDK version is v19.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif?rq=1

Comment: Better yet. Instead of making ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener... use the one you allready have in the adapter. mItemClickListener. Make it public so you can initialize from the activity and then handle it from there (Activity)... i think that would be more like an itemOnclickListener of a ListView... :).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add a click after finding View like this:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            txtViewId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
           // here 
           itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Comment: oh... my...... how did I miss this. Thank you so much. I already tried adding the exact code to my onCreateViewHolder. So stupid of me not adding it to the ViewHolder.

Comment: need to wait 1 min before accepting ^^

Comment: This may work but is not the proper way on how to do it. Follow this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/1137730

Answer (score 1):

You did not set `ClickListener` to the `textView` or Anything. On what `View` is `onClick` supposed to call?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Change Constructor

```
 public ProjectAdapter(List<Project> itemsData,OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemsData = itemsData;
        onItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }
```

Step 2: Give reference to interface

```
 public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);    
}
```

Step 3: Give listener to adapter from activity Or Fragment

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter (list, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set item click listener to recycler view row:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                   TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
                   String id = tv.getText().toString();
                   mItemClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v, id);
              }
        });
        txtViewName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        txtViewId = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);

    }
```