# OnItemClickListener vs OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have read many posts about implementing an `OnItemClickListener` in the `RecyclerView`, but the more I read, the more I get confused. It seems that we have two ways to implement the `OnItemClickListener`:

1. Adding `setOnClickListener` inside the adapter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/5107560)
2. Implementing `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196831/5107560)

As I read the posts I figure out that the first method is better and has more features than the second method. For example, there's item click support. What is the benefit of the second method? Why and whe should I use it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OnItemTouchListener` functions a bit differently than the normal `OnItemClickListener`. Using the `OnItemTouchListener`, it is possible to allow the application to intercept touch events from the `View` hierarchy. What this basically means is that you can implement various forms of gesture manipulation like swipe straight into the `View`s of your `RecyclerView`.

> **When should you use it?**
>   An `OnItemClickListener` should be used when you need to determine what happens when the user clicks on a `View` in your `RecyclerView`. This could be deleting something or starting up a new activity. The `OnItemTouchListener` Is generally used to create gestural interactivity to certain `View`s in your `RecyclerView`.

If you want to implement an `OnItemTouchListener` into your `RecyclerView`, you will need to determine the `MotionEvent` that you're going to use. For more information, I suggest you read more about [`OnItemTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html) from the Android Developers site.