# Swipe left and swipe right on GridView

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I want to perform right swipe and swipe left on GridView in fragment. If I used any swipe gesture on GridView then GridView's click and long click is not working. Can someone help me that how can i perform swipe left and swipe right on GridView with onclick and longclick.

Answer (score 0):

Use Recycler view with GridLayoutManager. Recycler view have nice api for swipe. for click listener you can create onclick listener in view holder also or you can implement using itemtouch listener. For more check this so answer -

[Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

Comment: @Dhanveerthakur if my answer is helpful then accept it.