# Can't open fragment from RecyclerView item Click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

Hi I have a simple app that features a recyclerView with list items (each representing a "Movie" object. The content for the movie list items is generated from an API call (themoviedb.org). I'm trying to open a "detail fragment" by clicking on a recyclerView list item. I want all of the content from the Movie item clicked to appear in the next fragment as well. Right now when I click the list item, nothing happens. No crash, even. I thought I had set up the listener interface correctly, but maybe that's the problem. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the Fragment where the RecyclerView (movie list) first appears:

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
Movie_Results_Adapter results_adapter;
ArrayList<Movie> movieList;
onMovieSelectedListener listener;
public ResultsFragment(){
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_1, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    results_adapter = new Movie_Results_Adapter(movieList, listener);
    listener = new onMovieSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovieSelected(Movie selectedMovie) {
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MovieDetailActivity.class);
            launchIntent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, "movie");
            Log.d("PaulsApp", selectedMovie + "");
            launchIntent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.NEW_EXTRA, (Serializable) selectedMovie);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
    };
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(results_adapter);
    Log.d("TAGG", "AAAH" + movieList.toString());
    return rootView;
}

public void parseJson(String jsonToParse) throws JSONException {


    JSONObject responseObject= new JSONObject(jsonToParse);
    JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");
    for(int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject movie = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String movieName = movie.getString("title");
        String movieReleaseDate = movie.getString("release_date");
        String movieScore = movie.getString("vote_average");
        String moviePopularity = movie.getString("vote_count");
        String movieImage = movie.getString("poster_path");
        String movieDescription = movie.getString("overview");
        Movie movie1 = new Movie(movieName, movieReleaseDate, movieScore, moviePopularity, movieImage, movieDescription);
        movieList.add(movie1);
    }

}

@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    String arguments = args.getString("JSON_STRING");
    try {
        parseJson(arguments);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.setArguments(args);
}

public interface onMovieSelectedListener{
    public void onMovieSelected(Movie selectedMovie);
}
```

}

Here is the RecyclerView Adapter for the "results" fragment:

```
public class Movie_Results_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Movie_Results_Adapter.ResultViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<Movie> MovieListArray;
    ResultsFragment.onMovieSelectedListener listener;
    private Activity mActivity;



    public class ResultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView titleText;
        TextView dateText;
        TextView scoreText;
        TextView popularityText;
        ImageView movieImage;
        public Movie movie;
        public ResultViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            titleText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title_text);
            dateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_date_text);
            scoreText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_score_text);
            popularityText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_popularity_text);
            movieImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onMovieSelected(MovieListArray.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "clicked: " + MovieListArray.get(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    public Movie_Results_Adapter(ArrayList<Movie> movieList, ResultsFragment.onMovieSelectedListener listener){
        MovieListArray = movieList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public ResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_result_list_item, parent, false);

        ResultViewHolder vh = new ResultViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ResultViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.titleText.setText(MovieListArray.get(position).getmTitle());
        Log.d("TAGG", MovieListArray.toString());
        holder.dateText.setText("Released "+MovieListArray.get(position).getmReleaseYear());
        holder.scoreText.setText("TMDB Score:  "+MovieListArray.get(position).getmScore());
        holder.popularityText.setText(MovieListArray.get(position).getmPopularity()+" votes");
        Context context = holder.movieImage.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(Constants.TMDB_POSTER+MovieListArray.get(position).getmImage()).into(holder.movieImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return MovieListArray.size();
    }


}
```

Here is the detail fragment (and accompanying activity):

```
package jetsetpaul.movienerd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by pauljoiner on 8/17/16.
 */
public class MovieDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public String movieTitle;
    public String movieImage;
    public String movieDate;
    public String movieDescription;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_detail_fragment, container, false);
        TextView mTitleText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_title);
        ImageView mMovieImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_image);
        TextView mDateText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_release_date);
        TextView mDescriptionText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_description);
        mTitleText.setText(movieTitle);
        mDateText.setText(movieDate);
        mDescriptionText.setText(movieDescription);
        Context context = mMovieImage.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(Constants.TMDB_POSTER+movieImage);

        return rootView;
    }
    public void setMovieTitle(String title){
        this.movieTitle = title;
    }
    public void setMovieImage(String image){
        this.movieImage = image;
    }
    public void setMovieDate(String date){
        this.movieDate = date;
    }
    public void setMovieDescription(String description){
        this.movieDescription = description;
    }
}
```

Activity:
    package jetsetpaul.movienerd;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by pauljoiner on 8/17/16.
 */
public class MovieDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MOVIE = "movie";
    public static final String NEW_EXTRA = "movie2";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if(i.hasExtra(NEW_EXTRA)) {
            Log.d("PaulsApp", "Had Extra!");
            //set the text in my fragment
           Movie movie = (Movie) i.getSerializableExtra(NEW_EXTRA);
            Fragment newFragment = new MovieDetailFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_fragment, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            ((MovieDetailFragment) newFragment).setMovieTitle(movie.getmTitle());
            ((MovieDetailFragment) newFragment).setMovieImage(movie.getmImage());
            ((MovieDetailFragment) newFragment).setMovieDate(movie.getmReleaseYear());
            ((MovieDetailFragment) newFragment).setMovieDescription(movie.getmDescription());

        }
    }
}
```

I can post more code if necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Answer (score 1):

Your listener needs to be created before your results_adapter

```
listener = new onMovieSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMovieSelected(Movie selectedMovie) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MovieDetailActivity.class);
        launchIntent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, "movie");
        Log.d("PaulsApp", selectedMovie + "");
        launchIntent.putExtra(MovieDetailActivity.NEW_EXTRA, (Serializable) selectedMovie);
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
};
results_adapter = new Movie_Results_Adapter(movieList, listener);
```

To be honest though, it would be best for your fragment to implement the listener (interface) instead of having to create it by using new onMovieSelectedListener().