# How to communicate between View and Adapter in MVP style

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm studying MVP style with [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

In this sample, Adapter(RecyclerViewAdapter etc) belongs to View.
Fragment means View in MVP and Adapter placed in the View as inner class.

In this case, a communication between View and Adapter was made by using callback interface.

```
    public TasksAdapter(List<Task> tasks, TaskItemListener itemListener) {
        setList(tasks);
        mItemListener = itemListener;
    }
```

I often though callback communication is a little confused.

Many reactions in this QA show this matter.

[Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

```
public class ReactiveAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    String[] mDataset = { "Data", "In", "Adapter" };

    private final PublishSubject<String> onClickSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String element = mDataset[position];

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               onClickSubject.onNext(element);
            }
        });
    }

    public Observable<String> getPositionClicks(){
        return onClickSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

There are some ways on this.

- Callbacks (callback, listener, and observer)
- Observable with RxJava
- PublishSubject with RxJava
- Event Bus
- Pass View or Presenter to Adapter's constructor

Which way is correct ? How should I do this?