# using onClickListener for recyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I faced with problem during using   onclickListener on Android.
i have written this code for onClick but while running the app it isn't response to my click.
I have create onClick on ViewHolder class and implemented the onClickListener interface.

this is my code:

```
public class AdapterLessons extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterLessons.ViewHolderLessons> {
private List<Lesson> mListLessons = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public Context context;


public AdapterLessons(Context context, List<Lesson> listLesson) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mListLessons = listLesson;
    this.context = context;

}
@Override
public ViewHolderLessons onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item_lesson, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolderLessons(view,context,mListLessons);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderLessons holder, final int position) {
    final Lesson currentLesson = mListLessons.get(position);

    holder.lessonText.setText(currentLesson.getLesssonName());

    if(currentLesson.get_id() % 2 == 0) {
        holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tablesecond);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tablefirst);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListLessons.size();
}

static class ViewHolderLessons extends ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView lessonText;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutLesson ;
    Context context;
    List<Lesson> lessonList = Collections.emptyList();


    ViewHolderLessons(View itemView, Context context,List<Lesson> lessonList) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        this.lessonList = lessonList;
        lessonText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lessonText);
        relativeLayoutLesson = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlTextLesson);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Lesson l = lessonList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, l.get_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no offense but, where are you setting the on click listener?

Comment: Where are you calling `setOnClickListener` on any of your views?

Comment: their is no setOnClickListener .To which element are you adding onClickListener?

Comment: where i should put it cause i have already created onClick method.

Comment: @Androidandroid Where I should put it???

Comment: inside your `ViewHolderLessons` constructor

Answer (score 1):

In the construtor of the holder you forgot to call this:

```
itemView.setOnclickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in onBindViewHolder:

```
   holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setTag(position);  

   holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                  Lesson l = lessonList.get(position);
                  Toast.makeText(context, l.get_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

for e.g. your onBindViewHolder() should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderLessons holder, final int position) {
    final Lesson currentLesson = mListLessons.get(position);

    holder.lessonText.setText(currentLesson.getLesssonName());

    if(currentLesson.get_id() % 2 == 0) {
        holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tablesecond);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tablefirst);
    }




 holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setTag(position);  

holder.relativeLayoutLesson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                  Lesson l = lessonList.get(position);
                  Toast.makeText(context, l.get_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter should delegate onClick event to an interface passed on the constructor. Check this answer: [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own OnClickListener.

At first create interface in your adapter class or as new file like this:

```
public interface OnLessonClickListener{
        void onLessonClick(Lesson lesson);
}
```

Then create an object of this interface in your adapter class:

```
private OnLessonClickListener listener;
```

Then you need to create method for initializing this listener:

```
public void setOnLessonClickListener(OnLessonClickListener l){
        listener = l;
}
```

After that in your ViewHolder class you should setOnClickListener on your itemView. And in method onClick make your click.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(listener != null) {
                    listener.onLessonClick(lessonList.get(getAdapterPosition));
                }
            });
```

The end of this mechanism will be implementing listener in class where you want to get you lesson object:

```
AdapterLessons adapter = new AdapterLessons(context, new ArrayList<Lesson>);
```

If you implemented listener:

```
adapter.setOnLessonClickListener(this)
```

If not:

```
adapter.setOnLessonClickListener(new OnLessonClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLessonClick(Lesson l){
        Log.e("TAGA", "Lesson is "+l);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Sorry for my English.