# RecyclerView - get Position inside Activity rather than RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

It is my third day now dealing with the handling of my view clicks. I originally was using `ListView`, then I switched to `RecyclerView`. I have added `android:onclick` elements to every control on my `row_layout` and I am handling them in my `MainActivity` like this:

```
public void MyMethod(View view) {}
```

In my old `ListView` implementation, I have done `setTag(position)` to be able to get it in `MyMethod` by doing this inside it:

```
Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())
```

This worked nicely without problems. Though now I am dealing with `RecyclerView` and being forced to use the `ViewHolder`, which does not offer a `setTag` method. After searching for 2 hours, I have found that people use `setTag` like this:

```
holder.itemView.setTag(position)
```

This was acceptable. Though when I try to get the value from the `MyMethod` function using the line:

```
Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())
```

The application crashes. I have read several implementation of onclick handling inside the adapter which works but I have to use the `MainActivity` because I am using something that is unique to that activity.

TL;DR I want to send the position of the clicked row to my `MainActivity` in a simple manner.

Edit: I apologize for the confusion since my topic was not very thorough. I have a `RecyclerView` and an adapter. The adapter is linked to my `row_layout`. This `row_layout` xml has one root `LinearLayout`. Inside it there is one `TextView`, another `LinearLayout` (which has two `TextViews`) and one `Button` (for simplicity). I do not want to suffer for dealing with the clicks on `RecylerView` like I did with the `ListView`. So, I have decided to add an `android:onclick` for every control, then link `TextView` and `LinearLayout` to a single method and link the `Button` (and future `Button`s) to their unique methods. What I am missing is that I want to be able to tell the position on each of the receiving methods on my `MainActivity`. If I must link everything that comes from the adapter and goes into the `MainActivity` to a single onclick handler, so be it. Although, how would I tell which control fired the click?

Edit 2: The requested layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:onClick="MyMethod"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/letter"
        android:onClick="MyMethod"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:onClick="MyMethod"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstname"
            android:onClick="MyMethod"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="17dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longname"
            android:onClick="MyMethod"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:text="Test"
        android:onClick="OtherMethod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/process"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Inside holder you can do getAdapterPosition to get the particular item position. Here no need to do `setTag()` and `getTag()`.

Comment: Yes, I can use that inside the adapter. Though, what I want is to be able to get the position in the MainActivity not inside the adapter itself.

Comment: Have you read over some of the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Comment: @cricket_007, yes it was one of the topics that I came across while I was searching for a solution to my problem.

Comment: please paste the adapter code here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating an interface inside your adapter for an `itemclicklistener` and then you can set `onItemClickListener` from your `MainActivity`.

Somewhere inside your `RecyclerViewAdapter` you would need the following:

```
private onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

 public void setOnItemClickListener(onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface onRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
        void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
    }
```

Then inside your `ViewHolder` (which I've added as an inner class inside my adapter), you would apply the listener to the components you'd like the user to click, like so:

```
class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView imageview;

        RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageview = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageview.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
```

This example shows an `onClickListener` being applied to the image inside a `ViewHolder`.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) { 
//perform click logic here (position is passed)
                    }
                });
```

To implement this code, you would `setOnItemClickListener` to your adapter inside `MainActivity` as shown above.

**EDIT**

Because the `View` is getting passed into the `OnItemClickListener`, you can perform a `switch` statement inside the listener to ensure that the right logic is being performed to the right component. All you would need to do is take the logic from the `MyMethod` function and copy and paste it to the component you wish it to be applied to.

Example:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) { 
        Switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.letter:
               //logic for TextView with ID Letter here
            break;
            case R.id.firstname:
               //logic for TextView with ID firstname here
            break;
            ....
            //the same can be applied to other components in Row_Layout.xml
        }
                        }
                    });
```

You would also need to change something inside the `ViewHolder`. instead of applying the `OnClickListener` to an `ImageView`, you would need to apply to the whole row like so:

```
 RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.imageview = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.image);
                view.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
```

**EDIT 2**

Explanation:

So, with every `RecyclerView`. You need three components, The `RecyclerView`, `RecyclerViewAdapter` and the `RecyclerViewHolder`. These are what define the actual components the user sees (`RecyclerView`) and the Items within that View. The Adapter is where everything is pieced together and the Logic is implemented. The ins and outs of these components are nicely explained by Bill Phillips with the article [`RecyclerView` Part 1: Fundamentals For `ListView` Experts](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/) over at Big Nerd Ranch.

But to further explain the logic behind the click events, it's basically utilizing an [interface](http://httphttps://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to pass information from the `RecyclerViewAdapter` to the `RecyclerViewHolder` to your `MainActivity`. So if you follow the life-cycle of the `RecyclerView` adapter, it'll make sense.

The adapter is initialized inside your `MainActivity`, the adapter's constructor would then be called with the information being passed. The components would then be passed into the adapter via the `OnCreateViewHolder` method. This itself tells the adapter, that's how you would like the list to look like. The components in that layout, would then need to be individually initialized, that's where the `ViewHolder` comes into play. As you can see like any other components you would initialize in your `Activities`, you do the same in the `ViewHolder` but because the `RecyclerViewAdapter` inflates the `ViewHolder` you can happily use them within your adapter as shown by Zeeshan Shabbir. But, for this example you would like multiple components to have various logic applied to each individual one in your `MainActivity` class.

That's where we create the click listener as a global variable (so it can be accessed by both the `ViewHolder` and the `Adapter`) the adapter's job in this case is to ensure the listener exists by creating an `Interface` you can initialize the listener through.

```
 public interface onRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
 }
```

After you've defined the information you would like the interface to hold (E.G. the component and it's position), you can then create a function in which the adapter will call to apply the logic from your `Activity` (same way you would called `View.OnClickListener`) but by creating a `setOnItemClickListener`, you can customize it.

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(onRecyclerViewItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
```

This function then needs `onRecyclerViewItemClickListener` variable passed to it, as seen in your `MainActivity`. `new RecyclerViewAdapter.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener()` in this case it's the interface you created before with the method inside that would need to be implemented hence the

```
@Override
                public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
                }
```

is called.

All the `ViewHolder` does in this scenario is pass the information (The components it's self and the position) into the `onItemClickListener` with the components attached (inside the `onClick` function) to finalize the actual click functionality.

if you would like me to update the explanation in anyway, let me know.

Comment: This is really a nice solution. Though, I do not think it will work for my case. I could be wrong. though, since I am still learning. From my understanding, this will work for only one control. If I set it to multiple controls (Button, TextView, etc.). They will all lead to one click handler on my MainActivity. So, I would not be able to distinguish which control got the click and deal with its logic. I am using the android:onclick option to be able to receive the clicks on multiple methods on my activity. If I can only get the setTag to work in my case, that would end my suffering.

Comment: you can apply the logic to several different cases, this is just an example of an image. You should really be adding onclicklisteners to the components within the MainActivity that are unique to that activity (e.g. XML) and I would say apply this logic to any items that are within the RecyclerView. There's no elegant way around using a RecyclerView without a ViewHolder for the layout of the items in the RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you add the XML for the row_layout?

Comment: Because you're inflating this layout inside your adapter, this solution would be the cleanest. Ill add an edit to show you how you can differentiate between the different components using a switch statement.

Comment: check the edit. this would be the most viable solution for you.

Comment: Wow, this is what I was looking for exactly. Thanks a lot. I really really appreciate it. I ended up removing the onclick elements from my xml and programmatically adding them on the RecyclerViewHolder's constructor. If it is not much to ask, can you explain to me how your solution works, exactly. I am new to the android programming. Thanks again. Edit: I saw the last part and used it instead of the messy Layout clicks handling.

Comment: let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. It did not make sense at first. So, I had to take a break from all the suffering. I cannot believe I have spent days on an interface issue. I hope I do not have any similar problems with the rest of controls. It is really a brilliant solution. You are using the MainActivity to call the adapter with an instance of the custom clicking method. Then, you capture the clicks at the ViewHolder level and redirect them to clicking custom interface method. Thanks again for the fantastic solution.

Comment: What should I do if I want to implement and OnKeyPressed action in one editText of an item from the list?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stuck with handling multiple clicks on `ReceylerView` if that is the case then let me share you the a code snippet from my project. That's how i handle the click in `RecyclerView`

```
public class ExploreItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExploreItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private WSResponseDTO<Data> wsResponseDTO;

public ExploreItemAdapter(WSResponseDTO<Data> wsResponseDTO) {
    this.wsResponseDTO = wsResponseDTO;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.consumer_dashboard_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tvCompanyName.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getStoreInfo().getStoreName());
    holder.tvBranchName.setText("(" + wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getStoreInfo().getBranchName() + ")");
    holder.tvLikes.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getFavoriteCount() + "");
    holder.tvShares.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getShareCount() + "");
    holder.validity.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getValidFrom() + "-" +
            wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getValidTo());
    holder.sTime.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getTime());
    holder.tvTitle.setText(wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position).getPost().getHeading());
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "card is touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), ConsumerDetailOfferActivity.class).putExtra("post", wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().get(position)));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return wsResponseDTO.getData().getPosts().size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.card_explore)
    CardView cardView;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_company_name)
    TextView tvCompanyName;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_branch_name)
    TextView tvBranchName;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_title)
    TextView tvTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_like_count)
    TextView tvLikes;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_share_count)
    TextView tvShares;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_validity)
    TextView validity;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_sTime)
    TextView sTime;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
}
```

you can set click listener to any item in bindViewHolder() like i did for `cardView` I hope this will help some.

Comment: I am not stuck with the multiple click handling per se. What I need is to find a simple way to present the RecyclerView clicked position to my MainActivity while knowing what control caused it. I can implement the click handling for all my controls and do it within the adapter and I would not have to deal with any issues if it was not for me needing to use a resource that is only available within the MainActivity. Thanks for the feedback. Much Appreciated.

Comment: consider passing that resource into adapter.