# Can't scroll RecyclerView because OnClick in the ViewHolder

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, touch-event

I have an RecyclerView inside a fragment that cannot scroll when I implement OnClick in a ViewHolder.

When I implement the OnClick the list is stock.

I use v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); to get focus because of the AppBarLayout that is stealling my vertical scrolling.

JAVA:

```
private void initRecycleView() {
    autoCompleteAdapter = new AutoCompleteSearchAdapter(getActivity(), this);
    autoCompleteList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    autoCompleteList.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
    autoCompleteList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
      >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/widget_search_bar"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried without setOnTouchListener ?

Comment: if i Implement parentView.setOnTouchListener it will scroll but how I can get the OnClick behavior from it?

Comment: you want to get itemClick of recyclerview. am i correct?

Comment: yes, I want to get item click from each item that is not a HEADER type.

Comment: what `OnClick`? there is no `OnClick` in your code

Comment: setOnTouchListener remove it and follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Comment: right because the onClick is in the ViewHolder

Comment: and what does `OnClick` have to do with the scrolling?

Comment: AppBarLayout that is stealling my vertical scrolling so I use  v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) and then if I implement OnClick in the ViewHolder - no scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a `setOnItemClickListener` interface for each of the `itemView`s as I've provided an answer for it here including an explanation of the process. [RecyclerView - get Position inside Activity rather than RecyclerViewAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041153/recyclerview-get-position-inside-activity-rather-than-recyclerviewadapter/41041685#41041685)