# Wrong item in recyclerview after filtering

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hi i have a RecyclerView adapter as follow :-

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        List<Data> list = Collections.emptyList();
        Context context;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Data> list, Context context) {
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.apps_layout, parent, false);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            return holder;

        }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

        ((ViewHolder)holder).itemView.clearAnimation();
    }

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
            holder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
            holder.description.setText(list.get(position).description);

        }

    public void setFilter(List<Data> searched_data) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(searched_data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

        // Insert a new item to the RecyclerView on a predefined position
        public void insert(int position, Data data) {
            list.add(position, data);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }

        // Remove a RecyclerView item containing a specified Data object
        public void remove(Data data) {
            int position = list.indexOf(data);
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

    }
```

okay now as you can see setFilter method to filter recyclerview list

here is how i call it

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
               return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                List<Data> filteredModelList = filter(data, s);
                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

now filter works fine now when i click on it the position is wrong

i know the error coming from the position as the older recyclerview on click has old position index i dont know how to fix it anyway here is onclicklistener

```
data = appsdata(); // load the list List<Data>

        Collections.sort(data); // sorting

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                String s = data.get(position).title;
                String ss = data.get(position).description;

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcitivity.this, Work.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", s);
                intent.putExtra("desc", ss);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }));
```

i know this line is causing problem

```
String s = data.get(position).title;
```

because it is same as old when list was not filtered ,how i can update this recyclerview so that i can get updated index when launching Work.class

Answer (score 1):

okay guys this what works partially for me

i tried updating the data list by adding

```
data = filteredModelList;  // add this line
```

after filtering and this worked fine

```
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                List<Data> filteredModelList = filter(data, s);
                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
                data = filteredModelList;  // add this line
                return true;
            }
```

now i get real index but when i search and clear the list the list is empty because i replaced the data list :(

**EDIT :- i fixed it by hack not a nice way but works**

as you can see the old list was gone by using above stuff before edit

when i used to change the data list

```
 data = filteredModelList;  // add this line
```

then the new data list has only filtered values and when you clear searchView then that data list is empty because it does not have those all apps list what i did was that i made new list as data_fix and onclicklistener i used datafix instead of data list

see this how

RecyclerItemClickListener method

```
String s = datafix.get(position).title;  // data.get to datafix.get
String ss = datafix.get(position).description; // data.get to datafix.get
```

now onsetfilter call 
i called this

```
datafix = filteredModelList; // instead of data = filteredModelList;
```

also i initialize it oncreate so it is not empty on launch of the app by

```
data = appsdata(); // load the list List<Data>
datafix = appsdata(); // load the list List<Data>  added just below it to intialize
```

now this way the full loaded applist // List data stays full and doesnot clear even if you clear from searchView and index is all right

Comment: so at the end of addition the recyclerview should only contain only the updated data only!

Comment: i updated it see my answer it works but not a nice way to do it though

Comment: it is see this,this is also seems same question just got to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634533/getting-wrong-item-on-recyclerview-list-filtering-selection  ,it does not work as expected but atleast my small hack work but still i feel this is not a good because i have to use two different list

Answer (score 0):

The logic lies to how you update the recycler view items,

```
public void setFilter(List<Data> searched_data) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(searched_data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

> The above line is not necessary, `adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(data, this);` this line is very important to understand. You see when you pass data to the adapter is like this you are creating a symbolic link between the list in the adapter and outside. So therefore any changes made to the outside list, to update the adapter version.Just call  `adapter.notifyDatasetChange method`
>   do this whenever any changes are made to the data model object.

CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FROM

```
  List<Data> filteredModelList = filter(data, s);
                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
                data = filteredModelList;  // add this line
                return true;
```

> TO,

```
 adapter.list.clear();
    data = filter(data, s);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: so setFilter(List<Data> searched_data), is not needed, any where outside the adapter you modify the original object, just call adapter.notifyDatasetChange();, right after modification.

Comment: this wont work either due to the List<Data> i am using is still old because i get position from that list and the old list is there

Comment: just try it, did you?

Comment: wait a sec let me do

Comment: did not work either,see my answer below which works partially but list is gone

Comment: to be honest I am lost , to what exactly is your problem.

Comment: yes no items because when i add  data = filteredModelList;  // add this line  as you can see below in my answer then the data list is updated with filterted and when the next time a char is added or deleted from the searchview then the data list which should have original data is decreased to filtered

Comment: does not work list is all cleared because you used adapter.clear ,