# Perform click event on RecyclerView's item by "Position"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am in RecyclerView's Adapter.

From onBindViewHolder() I am able to perform onClick event for RecyclerView's row (ViewHolder's Item).

Is it possible to call onClick() by using Position ?

Comment: Yes its possible.

Comment: Show your adapter please.

Comment: @PatelJaimin Can you please help me out ? Any particular methods of RecyclerView.ViewHolder ?

Comment: Check out this answer. Maybe this is what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29142005/1649353

Comment: It will perform click event by position automatically.Please see my example below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

Adapter:

```
public class OffersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Offer> mDataset;
    private OffersListner mListener;

    public OffersAdapter(List<Offer> response) {
        mDataset = response;
    }

    public void setListener(OffersListner listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row_offers, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int pos = getItemViewType(position);

        holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onOfferChoice(mDataset.get(pos));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public interface OffersListner {
        void onOfferChoice(Offer offer);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.item_offers_layout)
        LinearLayout mLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class OffersSelectActivity extends BaseEventActivity implements OffersAdapter.OffersListner {
.
.
.

    private void setOffers(List<Offer> offers) {
        OffersAdapter mAdapter = new OffersAdapter(offers);
        mAdapter.setListener(this);

        mOffers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mOffers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mOffers.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }



    @Override
    public void onOfferChoice(Offer offer) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OfferActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OFFER_ID, offer.id);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OFFER_NAME, offer.name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example :

```
 public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Pojo_menu> data;

public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context mContext, List<Pojo_menu> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView title, tv_count;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        tv_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_nav_menu);

    }

}

public NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
    return new NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Pojo_menu current = data.get(position);
    String count = current.getCount();
    holder.tv_count.setText(count);
    holder.title.setText(current.getName());
    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `onClickListener` to the holder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // to the thing you want refer to the position by holder.getAdapterPosition()
        }
      };)
    }
```

It not recommended to use `position` directly since you have to declare it `final`. Therefore, when referring to the position inside `onClick` please use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` instead.