# How to make click listener in recyclerview in android?

Tags: android

I have a recycler view which contain some items in list and in individual items contain a button. i want to perform some action on button click on particular item i implemented Recycler view adapter but don't want to implement code in button click in adapter i want to perform action in fragmenr which contain recylcer view impelementation. How do i do that

code for adapter

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView m_premiumText, m_getDealText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        m_premiumText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_premiun_deals);
        m_getDealText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_get_deals);

        m_getDealText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"clicked"+getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

code for recycler view

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = getActivity();
    main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reward_premium_deals, container, false);
    findViewById();
    initControls();
    return main;
}


public void findViewById() {
    m_premiumList = (RecyclerView) main.findViewById(R.id.premium_list);
    m_layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    m_premiumList.setLayoutManager(m_layoutManager);

}

public void initControls() {
    premiumNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.premium_deals_title);
    m_premiumDealsAdapter = new CPremiumDealsAdapter(mContext, premiumNames);
    m_premiumList.setAdapter(m_premiumDealsAdapter);

    /*here i want button click action*/


}
```

Comment: There are million resources already regarding this. If you have specific question regarding the implementation, create that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

in these cases you must use an listener or callback and send it to your recycler view adapter through constructor.

firstly create a new interface to use as the callback. then implement that interface in your fragment and then send your fragment (this) as the listener to your adapter. then you can call that action from your recycler view instance.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick), I have implemented in recycler view item in my `activity` class not in `fragment`.

1. Interface Class:

   ```
   public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
       void onClick(View view, int position);
       void onLongClick(View view, int position);
   }
   ```
2. RecyclerViewTouchListener Class:

   ```
   public class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
   private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
   private RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener;

   public RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener1) {
       recyclerViewClickListener = recyclerViewClickListener1;
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
               View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
               if (child != null && recyclerViewClickListener1 != null){
                   recyclerViewClickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
               }
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
       View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
       if (child != null && recyclerViewClickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
           recyclerViewClickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildLayoutPosition(child));
       }
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

   }
   }
   ```
3. Now, inside `fragment` or `activity` class where you have to setup you recycler view activties:

   ```
   recyclerView.setAdapter(your_adapter_class_object);
   recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view, int position) {
           Loge("Item","Click");
       }

       @Override
       public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
           Loge("Item","Long Click");
       }
   }));
   ```