# i am working on recycler view to add item click listener but i am having errors as sdk is not recognizing methods of recycler view and gesture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, addition, ontouchlistener

i am working on recycler view to add item click listener but i am having error as sdk is not recognizing methods of recycler view and gesture also clicklistener interface is also implemented in touch listener class ... i am new at android this code snippet will help to get the idea of what i am doing...

here is the class for touch listener code:

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

```
void onLongClick(View view, int position);
```

}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
```

}

main_actvity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private List<Movie> movieList=new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter=new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    prepareMovieData();
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));


}
private void prepareMovieData(){

    Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("The Martian", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation", "Action", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Up", "Animation", "2009");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Star Trek", "Science Fiction", "2009");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("The LEGO Movie", "Animation", "2014");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Iron Man", "Action & Adventure", "2008");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Aliens", "Science Fiction", "1986");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Chicken Run", "Animation", "2000");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Back to the Future", "Science Fiction", "1985");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Action & Adventure", "1981");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Goldfinger", "Action & Adventure", "1965");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");``
    movieList.add(movie);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the support libraries to your `build.gradle`?

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

Comment: yes i did ... click listener interface is giving error "should be declared in separate class" ..