# How to handle RecyclerView click events in android activity instead of Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView which for each item contains a button. I want to handle the click event for this button in the activity holding the RecyclerView instead of inside the adapter as I have heard this is the best approach.

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class SearchResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<User> results;

    public SearchResultAdapter(List<User> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchResultAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_search_results_recycler_view, parent, false);
        return new SearchResultAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchResultAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String fullName = results.get(position).getFirstName() +
                " " + results.get(position).getLastName();
        holder.mFullNameTextView.setText(fullName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return results.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.search_full_name_text_view)
        TextView mFullNameTextView;

        @BindView(R.id.send_request_button)
        Button mSendRequestButton;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

How should I handle the click event of the `mSendRequestButton` with the corresponding `User` object from the `results` list to the activity? I can think of using an interface but maybe there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Using interface you can do it.

Comment: What about event bus?

Comment: Is the View Holder pattern best?

Comment: @TomFinet you want handle the click of button in the recycleview parent activity rigth?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, but what's the problem with interface? You question seems to be very broad/opinion based.

Comment: Yeh thats correct. No I was just wondering which is the accepted best way.

Comment: Does that apply to the entire item or can it be narrowed down to just the button click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener)