# Pass Item Position Clicked from a RecyclerView to the Fragment father

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've been trying to send the item position clicked from my `RecyclerView` to the `Fragment` father, I already saw many tutorials, but I have not been successful in doing this. Please help me on this specific case:

This is my `Adapter` Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
private HeaderViewHolder headerHolder;
private ArrayList<Doc> documentos;
private Context context;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private SQLiteHandler db;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Doc> generics) {
    this.context = context;
    this.documentos = generics;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder (v);
    } else if(viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_foter, parent, false);
        return new FooterViewHolder (v);
    } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        return new GenericViewHolder (v);
    }
    return null;
}

private Doc getItem (int position) {
    return documentos.get (position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        headerHolder.card_view_header.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                createDialogServices();
            }
        });
    } else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
        FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
        //footerHolder.txtTitleFooter.setText ("Footer");
        footerHolder.send_Button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Toast.makeText (context, "Enviando documentos...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }
        });
    } else if(holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
        Doc currentItem = getItem (position - 1);
        final Integer num = currentItem.getPosition();
        GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
        genericViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(currentItem.getTittle());
        genericViewHolder.txtDescription.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
        genericViewHolder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                ImagePicker.pickImage((Activity) context, "Select your image:");
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position) {
    if(isPositionHeader (position)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if(isPositionFooter (position)) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader (int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

private boolean isPositionFooter (int position) {
    return position == documentos.size () + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount () {
    return documentos.size () + 2;
}

private class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button send_Button;
    FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        this.send_Button = (Button) itemView.findViewById (R.id.btn_send_docs);
    }
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView card_view_header;
    TextView card_txt_title;
    TextView card_txt_description;
    HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);
        this.card_view_header = (CardView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.card_view_header);
        this.card_txt_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_textView_tittle);
        this.card_txt_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_textView_description);
    }
}

private class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDescription;
    GenericViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_item_textView_tittle);
        this.txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_item_textView_description);
    }
}
```

And this is my `Fragment` Class:

```
public class FragmentArchivos extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView.Adapter MyAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView rv;
private Button btn_send_fr_docs;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView photo;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private Integer x;


public FragmentArchivos(){
    //Empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_docs, container, false);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

    getAllDocsFromServer();
    x = db.getDocsCount();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById (R.id.cardList);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity());
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getDocumentList());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);

    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Your recycleview is inside other fragment?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira No, the RecyclerView is inside the FragmentArchivos  Fragment.

Comment: ok I understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;
    private HeaderViewHolder headerHolder;
    private ArrayList<Doc> documentos;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Doc> generics, MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.documentos = generics;
this. myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_header, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder (v);
        } else if(viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_foter, parent, false);
            return new FooterViewHolder (v);
        } else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
            return new GenericViewHolder (v);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Doc getItem (int position) {
        return documentos.get (position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
            headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
            headerHolder.card_view_header.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view) {
myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition())
                    createDialogServices();
                }
            });
        } else if(holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            //footerHolder.txtTitleFooter.setText ("Footer");
            footerHolder.send_Button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view) {
myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition())
                    Toast.makeText (context, "Enviando documentos...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
            });
        } else if(holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
            Doc currentItem = getItem (position - 1);
            final Integer num = currentItem.getPosition();
            GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
            genericViewHolder.txtTitle.setText(currentItem.getTittle());
            genericViewHolder.txtDescription.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
            genericViewHolder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View view) {
myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition())

                    ImagePicker.pickImage((Activity) context, "Select your image:");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType (int position) {
        if(isPositionHeader (position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        } else if(isPositionFooter (position)) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader (int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private boolean isPositionFooter (int position) {
        return position == documentos.size () + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return documentos.size () + 2;
    }

    private class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button send_Button;
        FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            this.send_Button = (Button) itemView.findViewById (R.id.btn_send_docs);
        }
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView card_view_header;
        TextView card_txt_title;
        TextView card_txt_description;
        HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            this.card_view_header = (CardView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.card_view_header);
            this.card_txt_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_textView_tittle);
            this.card_txt_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_header_textView_description);
        }
    }

    private class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDescription;
        GenericViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_item_textView_tittle);
            this.txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_item_textView_description);
        }


public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClicked(int position);
}



}
```

in FragmentArchivos class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_docs, container, false);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

    getAllDocsFromServer();
    x = db.getDocsCount();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById (R.id.cardList);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity());
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getDocumentList(), new MyClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {

 //TODO do ur work here

    }


});
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);

    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, this one works for me! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this way.

First create na interface like that named `RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack` :

```
public interface RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack {
    public void onClickListener(View view, int position);
    public void onLongPressClickListener(View view, int position);

}
```

And then in fragment do this:

1) implements RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack;

2) Add methods;

3) Then inside Onclick method you have a parameter position. method be like this:

```
 @Override

    public void onClickListener(View view, int position) {

    }
```

4) Finally add this to recycleview inside oncreateview() method:

```
recyclerViewtodas.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(getActivity(), your_recycleview, this));
```

So full code be like this:

```
public class separadortodas extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack {
...

@Override

    public void onClickListener(View view, int position) {


    }

    @Override

    public void onLongPressClickListener(View view, int position) {



    }



    private static class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private Context mContext;

        private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

        private RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack;



        RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context c, final RecyclerView rv, RecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack rvoclh){

            mContext = c;

            mRecyclerViewOnClickListenerHack = rvoclh;



            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

                @Override

                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                    super.onLongPress(e);



                }



                @Override

                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return(true);

                }

            });

        }



        @Override

        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);

            return false;

        }



        @Override

        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {}

        @Override

        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView has setOnItemClickListener() method but RecyclerView has not. Link below is your solution:

[Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener)

Edit: If you want to call this functionality from your activity, you need something like below:

First add a method in your activity (which has this RecyclerView) with proper parameters. Secondly, you can cast your context variable to your activity. Cast it and call your method. Now your activity has a listener for which item clicked.