# Android - Open new activity on item clicked in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a simple app for newbies, but I'm stuck at the main part. I created RecyclerView list. I want to know how to open a new Activity clicking on the first item in the ListView (see in screenshot).

Here is my MainActivity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    private ArrayList<String> countries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add("Computer");
        countries.add("RAM");
        countries.add("ROM");
        countries.add("MotherBoard");
        countries.add("Printer");
        countries.add("CPU");
        countries.add("Pendrive");
        countries.add("Keyboard & Mouse");
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new DataAdapter(countries);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                    int position = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), countries.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> countries;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView tv_country;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_country = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: See accepted answer here. -> Add ClickListener to your ViewHolder.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

You should use onItemClickListener or OnClickListener

```
 recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 ...
 }
```

Comment: can you tell me in details plzz

Comment: Instead of using this `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener()` you should use the method I said in the answer. Another possibility is to add a onclick method to the adapter, for when the user clicks each textview

Comment: thanks bro problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

In the onBindViewHolder function add onClickListner on items.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
    viewHolder.tv_country.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}
```

In this example i added onCLickListner on tv_country. If you need further help ask me in comments.

Comment: Always Welcome!