# Calling a method from Activity in Adapter

Tags: java, android, list, adapter, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to load data from my server in a `RecyclerView`. I have successfully implement the `Get`, and `Post` Retrofit methods but I am facing some problems for the `Put` and `Delete` ones. Since `ReclyclerView` requires an `Adapter` to load the data, and I need to get the position of the row that I am clicking, I had to implement the `onKeyPressed` (because I am using and EditText) inside my `Adapter`.

The problem is that the method that calls my `Interceptor`, the Retrofit call and Everything is in my `Activity`.
So i decided to call the method from this Activity inside my Adapter to do the Put and Delete of a singular item. But I am getting a

> java.lang.ClassCastException saying that the method cannot be casted
>   to the Adapter.

This is the onKeyPressed method, ViewCategoryActivity si my Activity and SendNetworkRequest is my method:

```
holder.nameCategory.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    System.out.println("Entrou no adapter!!");
                    Category2 category = new Category2();
                    category.setName(holder.nameCategory.getText().toString());
                    ((ViewCategoriesActivity)mContext).SendNetworkRequest(categoryList.get(position).getProjectId(), 2, categoryList.get(position).get_id(), new SendCategory(holder.nameCategory.getText().toString()));

                    //Variable to check if the category inserted is equal to a previous one
                    int bool = 0;
                    //The for goes through the list and tries to find a category with the name equal to the one inserted
                    for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++){

                        //if it finds equal names bool = 1
                        if (categoryList.get(i).getName().equals(holder.nameCategory.getText().toString())){
                            bool = 1;
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.category_different_name),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    //There's no category with the same name so it' OK so insert a new one
                    if (bool == 0){

                        if(mContext instanceof ViewCategoriesActivity){
                            ((ViewCategoriesActivity)mContext).SendNetworkRequest(categoryList.get(position).getProjectId(), 2, categoryList.get(position).get_id(), new SendCategory(holder.nameCategory.getText().toString()));
                        }
                        //categoryList.add(category);

                    } else {

                    }


                    // hide virtual keyboard
                    InputMethodManager imm =
                            (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.nameCategory.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: don't do this. Use a callback instead

Comment: which method cannot be cast?

Comment: post your callstack

Comment: How can I do that using callback? Would you mind explain it to me?

Comment: SendNetworkRequest is the method that I was not able to cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing a listener from your activity to the adapter. You should be then using that listener to call the function in your activity. i.e, if you are calling your adapter like the following,

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
```

where data can be an arraylist(suppose), then pass the context like this

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(data,ViewCategoriesActivity.this);
```

Accept this listener using a constructor in your adapter and then call your activity function like listener.yourFunction()

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, could you explain it to me a little bit more?

Comment: in your activity :
adapter = new DataAdapter(data,ViewCategoriesActivity.this);
in your adapter class :

public DataAdapter(String data, Activity activity){

}

Comment: and then wherever needed call activity.SendNetworkRequest()

Comment: I am calling my adapter like this: adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listCategories);

Comment: It worked by calling it like this: adapter = new CategoryAdapter(ViewCategoriesActivity.this, listCategories); Could you explain the difference for me?

Comment: instead of getApplicationContext() use ViewCategoriesActivity.this , please post your complete adapter class

Comment: by passing ViewCategoriesActivity.this, you can now have access to this activity's context in your adapter and hence you can use the funtions in your adapter

Comment: :) glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the listener easily, try not to make your code that complex. As per i know your problem has good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/6049494), hope it will work.