# RelativeLayout onClick attribute not working

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick

I am showing a List in a ListView through a custom adapter `SongsListAdapter.java` with custom itemview `music_item.xml` and there is a method i want to call in my Activity Class `MainActivity.java` so i cannot use `setOnClickListener` method
what i did is i added an attribute to `music_item.xml` `onClick`to call method in `MainActivity.java`
but this is not working, by clicking the list item it is not invoking the method from Activity class

**SongsListAdapter.java**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_item, null);
        this.mView = view;
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        holder.descr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songArtists);
        holder.dp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumIcon);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.title.setText(SongsListItemslist.get(position).getDisplayName());
    holder.descr.setText(SongsListItemslist.get(position).getArtist());
    holder.dp.setImageBitmap(SongsListItemslist.get(position).getBitmap());
    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void songPicked(View view) {
    Log.v("clicked", "clicked");
    musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
    musicSrv.playSong();
}
```

**Music_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/card"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="songPicked" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/albumIcon"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And i couldn't able to see `clicked` in my Logs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this from your **SongsListAdapter.java**

```
   view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        }
    });
```

you are setting a onClick Listener with an empty action in your adapter that isn´t necessary, use only the method defined in your Layout:

```
android:onClick="songPicked"
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you cannot use setOnClickListener, I'm not sure why? In your adapter constructor, you can pass in the Activity, set it as a variable in your adapter class and use it in your on click listener to call a method defined in Activity.

Alternatively, use setOnItemClickListener in your activity or fragment (ie where you initially set the adapter).

Comment: i dont want to increase dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set a listener on the Layout of your list item Music_item.  This will be covered under the setOnItemClickListener of your ListView.

see: [setOnItemClickListener on custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709870/setonitemclicklistener-on-custom-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to remove

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
   }
});
```

and then if you want ot handle the click on the ListView you need to call this from the MainActivity

```
    list.setAdapter(yourCustomAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Log.v("clicked", "clicked");
            musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
            musicSrv.playSong();

        }
    });
```

Don't forget to remove onClick attribute from the RelativLayout.

Good luck..

Comment: that's a good idea 
never thought that for custom adapter
will use later