# moving intent of listview with database

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-activity

I am just learning Android.

I have a `listview` with data taken from the table 'alphabet' on the database server. Suppose the table consists of id A, B, and C...

1. Now when I select an item of ID A, the `listview` will be filled with data from different tables, eg. table 'number'
2. Then, when I select an item of ID B, the same `listview` will be filled with different data again, eg. table 'symbol'
3. And when I select an item of ID C, another activity will open (not `listview`) and fill data from other tables as well more or less as it is

Is there a tutorial describing the same problem I mentioned above? Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this, you need to use setOnItemclickListener() of Listview.
By using this,You can get on which Item (A,B or C) , User have clicked.
and on based on that,With switch case,you can populate your data accordingly.
For more info on setOnItemclickListener(),
Refer this link : [setOnItemClickListener on custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709870/setonitemclicklistener-on-custom-listview)