# OnItemclickListner Toast message not showing in android

Tags: android, android-toast

Hi in the below code implemented autocomplete textview dynamically and saving the response locally.Now If am search for letter 'a' then from that is it displaying and settext to autocomplete textview.setext is working fine when I am selected the text want to get the Id

Onitemclick Toast message is not displaying.

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

```
 private void fetchProductnameJSON(){
        autoproduct_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml ( "Item Name"+""));
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                String operation = "syncModuleRecords";
                String module = "Products";
                String syncToken = "";
                String mode = "public";
                final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
                /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
                Call<SyncModule> call = service.GetSyncModuleList(operation, sessionId, module, syncToken, mode);

                /**Log the URL called*/
                Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

                call.enqueue(new Callback<SyncModule>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SyncModule> call, Response<SyncModule> response) {

                        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                            SyncModule syncModule = response.body();
                            Gson g = new Gson();
                            String jsonAllProducts = g.toJson(syncModule);
                            tinydb.putString("jsonAllProducts",jsonAllProducts);
                            workingOnResponseProduct(syncModule);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SyncModule> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                    //     progressDialog.dismiss();
                });
            }
        }, 0);
        return ;
    }

    private void workingOnResponseProduct(SyncModule syncModule) {
        autoproduct_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml ( "Item Name"+""));
        String success = syncModule.getSuccess();

        if (success.equals("true")) {

            SyncResults results = syncModule.getResult();

            Sync sync = results.getSync();

            ArrayList<SyncUpdated> syncUpdateds = sync.getUpdated();

            for (SyncUpdated syncUpdated : syncUpdateds) {

                String unitprice="";
                product_id = syncUpdated.getId();
                ArrayList<SyncBlocks> syncBlocks = syncUpdated.getBlocks();
                for (SyncBlocks syncBlocks1 : syncBlocks) {
                    String label = syncBlocks1.getLabel();
                    //Basic Information
                    if (label.equals("Product Details")) {
                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {

                            String name = synFields1.getName();
                            values = synFields1.getValue();

                            if (name.equals("productname")) {
                                productname = String.valueOf(values);
                                product_name.add(productname);
                                Log.d("products",String.valueOf(product_name.size()));
                                RecordsProducts records = new RecordsProducts(product_id,productname);
                                recordsListProduct.add(records);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //pricing information
                    else if (label.equals("Pricing Information")) {
                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {

                            String name = synFields1.getName();
                            values = synFields1.getValue();

                            if (name.equals("unit_price")) {
                                unitprice = String.valueOf(values);
                                Log.d("unitprice",unitprice);
                                //

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, product_name);
            autoproduct_name.setAdapter(adapter);

            autoproduct_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(position+1 > 0) {
                        RecordsProducts recordsProducts=recordsListProduct.get(position);
                        String product_id=recordsProducts.getId();
                        Log.d("productid",product_id);
                        String productnames=recordsProducts.getProductname();
                        autoproduct_name.setText(productnames);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"selected"+product_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
                TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
                Resources resource = getContext().getResources();
                tbrow0.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Product Name", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Quantity", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL,resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Unit Price", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Total", Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, resource.getColor(R.color.tabs1)));
                stk.addView(tbrow0,getLayoutParams());
                //String[] namesList = p.split(",");
                //String[] priceList = listprices.split(",");
        }
```

Comment: Hey where you have added OnItemClickListener? it is item selection listener which will work differently.

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: That is something different, it works when you select something. You need to change it to adapter.OnItemClickListener .

Comment: Checkout my answer please, it should resolve your problem now. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setOnItemClickListener on custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709870/setonitemclicklistener-on-custom-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution from this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752309/3811162

```
autoproduct_name.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     if(position+1 > 0) {
                    RecordsProducts recordsProducts=recordsListProduct.get(position);
                    String product_id=recordsProducts.getId();
                    Log.d("productid",product_id);
                    String productnames=recordsProducts.getProductname();
                    autoproduct_name.setText(productnames);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"selected"+product_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
   } 
});
```

Comment: above code giving me wrong id and wrong productname set to the autocompletetetextview

Comment: So here you can add your logic, I don't know what you want to achieve here. The If statement in the code you can think about it. There you can edit it :)